# How to convert an array into an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What is the best way to convert:

```
['a','b','c']
```

to:

```
{
  0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  2: 'c'
}
```

Comment: If anyone else is looking for a Lodash solution, consider `_.keyBy` (formerly `_.indexBy`): https://lodash.com/docs#keyBy

Comment: This is a bit confusing because arrays are objects already, but I guess the point of the question is converting the [array](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-exotic-objects) [exotic object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exotic-object) to an [ordinary object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object).

Comment: A simple way to do this with Lodash is `_.toPlainObject`.

Ex: `var myObj = _.toPlainObject(myArr)`

Answer (score 1020, accepted):

ECMAScript 6 introduces the easily polyfillable [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> The `Object.assign()` method is used to copy the values of all
> enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target
> object. It will return the target object.

```
Object.assign({}, ['a','b','c']); // {0:"a", 1:"b", 2:"c"}
```

The own `length` property of the array is not copied because it isn't enumerable.

Also, you can use ES8 [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) on objects to achieve the same result:

```
{ ...['a', 'b', 'c'] }
```

For custom keys you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: v}), {}) 
// { a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" }
```

Comment: Just want to point out - if you already have an array of sorted properties from the original object, using the **spread** operator is what will turn that array directly into a new object:
`{ ...[sortedArray]}`

Comment: Oriol, is there a way to set a fixed key instead of 0 & 1?

Comment: This is usually not what you want. Usually you want to use a property in the array element as a key. Thus, the reduce is what you want.

Comment: why mvc does not allow to us to post array. Why we must convert array to object?

Comment: what if i want the key not as 0,1,2 but the same as the value? like: {a: 'a'} How do we do that ?

Comment: @Gel Use `reduce` like: `arr.reduce((a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: v}), {})`

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, I can do: `{...arr}` and done

Comment: how can I reduce a large flat array of objects to one object, like `[{a:'b'},{c:'d'},,{}...]` to `{a:'b',c:'d',..}`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909965/1705829) it is

Comment: [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46928438/1705829) `reduce` and `Object.assign` together: `var newObj = arr.reduce((a, b) => Object.assign(a, b), {})`

Comment: What about doing the reverse? ie from { 0: 'a', 1: 'b, 3: 'd' } to [ 'a', 'b', , 'd' ] - kind of like Object.values() except ensuring the order and 'holes'...

Answer (score 558):

With a function like this:

```
function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    rv[i] = arr[i];
  return rv;
}
```

Your array already is more-or-less just an object, but arrays do have some "interesting" and special behavior with respect to integer-named properties. The above will give you a plain object.

*edit* oh also you might want to account for "holes" in the array:

```
function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    if (arr[i] !== undefined) rv[i] = arr[i];
  return rv;
}
```

In modern JavaScript runtimes, you can use the `.reduce()` method:

```
var obj = arr.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
  acc[i] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

That one also avoids "holes" in the array, because that's how `.reduce()` works.

Comment: thought this was great just added a few things for my own enjoyment returns an object you can't reference outside function so just showed example of that and adding something to the object property names
`x = ['a','b','c']
var b = {}
function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    if (arr[i] !== undefined) {
    rv['key_' + i] = arr[i];
    }
   b = rv
   return b;
}
toObject(x)
b.key_0`

Comment: What about `var arr = []; arr['foo'] = "bar"`? Can this be converted to object?

Comment: @m93a it already is an object. In JavaScript, there's really no point creating an Array instance (`[]`) if you're not going to use numeric property keys and the "length" property.

Comment: @Pointy Nope, it's not an usual object - try converting to JSON, it treats really werid.

Comment: @m93a All array instances are objects. Properties with string (non-numeric) names like "foo" are merely properties of that object, and as such they're just like properties of any other object. The properties with numeric names (like "12" or "1002") are special in that the runtime system automatically adjusts the "length" property accordingly when values are assigned. Also, `.push()`, `.pop()`, `.slice()`, etc. all only work on numeric properties, and not properties like "foo".

Comment: @Pointy Try to run this in your JS console: `var a = ["x", "y"]; a["foo"] = "z"; b = {1:"x",2:"y","foo":"z"}; console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); console.log(JSON.stringify(b));`.

Comment: @m93a the `JSON.stringify` code can tell the difference between a real Array instance and an object with numeric keys. When it sees a real array, all that it serializes is the "real" list of properties that comprise the numerically-indexed array. I have never noticed that behavior, but it's yet another good reason not to use an Array when you really just want an Object.

Comment: @Pointy, what are your one- and two-letter variables supposed to indicate?

Comment: @janaspage well "i" is just a numeric index into the numbered properties of the array, and "rv" is the return value of that function.

Comment: cleaner way to avoid param reassign `const obj = arr.reduce((obj, cur, i) => {
      return { ...obj, [i]: cur };
    }, {});`

Comment: If you had an array of objects and you would like to transform that array in a n object you could do: 
`const optionPriceArray = [ {option: 'economy', price:200}, {option: 'tourist', price:100} ]; `

and then:

`const newObj = optionPriceArray.reduce(function(acc, cur) { acc[cur.option] = cur.price; return acc; }, {});`

which outputs:
`//newObj = {'economy': 200, 'tourist': 100}`

Comment: @huygn will your approach be not more expensive in terms of number of lines that it has to process.Since everytime instead of using the same object, you are creating a new one by spreading the params which to es5 would be a for loop iterating over the properties.It seems that this might just make the function slow.What do you think?

Comment: Arrow + destructuring syntax w/o explicit return: `const obj = arr.reduce((obj, cur, i) => ({ ...obj, [i]: cur }), {});`

Comment: As @VivekN said, is it necessary to create new object every time? What about `arr.reduce((obj, cur, i) => (obj[i]=cur,obj), {});` ?

Comment: @eugene_sunic indeed, but that approach was not available when I answered this in 2010 :)

Comment: As @miro points out, creating a new object every time is not necessary, and in fact _much slower_ than manipulating the initial object that was created. Running a JSPerf test on an array of 1000 elements, creating a new object every time is **1,000** times slower than mutating the existing object. https://jsperf.com/array-prototype-reduce-mutate-vs-intermediate-objects

Answer (score 363):

You could use an accumulator aka [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
['a','b','c'].reduce(function(result, item, index, array) {
  result[index] = item; //a, b, c
  return result;
}, {}) //watch out the empty {}, which is passed as "result"
```

Pass an empty object `{}` as a starting point; then "augment" that object incrementally.
At the end of the iterations, `result` will be `{"0": "a", "1": "b", "2": "c"}`

If your array is a set of key-value pair objects:

```
[{ a: 1},{ b: 2},{ c: 3}].reduce(function(result, item) {
  var key = Object.keys(item)[0]; //first property: a, b, c
  result[key] = item[key];
  return result;
}, {});
```

will produce: `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`

For the sake of completeness, `reduceRight` allows you to iterate over your array in reverse order:

```
[{ a: 1},{ b: 2},{ c: 3}].reduceRight(/* same implementation as above */)
```

will produce: `{c:3, b:2, a:1}`

Your accumulator can be of any type for you specific purpose. For example in order to swap the key and value of your object in an array, pass `[]`:

```
[{ a: 1},{ b: 2},{ c: 3}].reduce(function(result, item, index) {
  var key = Object.keys(item)[0]; //first property: a, b, c
  var value = item[key];
  var obj = {};
  obj[value] = key;
  result.push(obj);
  return result;
}, []); //an empty array
```

will produce: `[{1: "a"}, {2: "b"}, {3: "c"}]`

Unlike `map`, `reduce` may not be used as a 1-1 mapping. You have full control over the items you want to include or exclude. Therefore `reduce` allows you to achieve what `filter` does, which makes `reduce` very versatile:

```
[{ a: 1},{ b: 2},{ c: 3}].reduce(function(result, item, index) {
  if(index !== 0) { //skip the first item
    result.push(item);
  }
  return result;
}, []); //an empty array
```

will produce: `[{2: "b"}, {3: "c"}]`

**Caution**: `reduce` and `Object.key` are part of `ECMA 5th edition`; you should provide a polyfill for browsers that don't support them (notably IE8).

See a default implementation by [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: Helpful with maintaining a redux store when you are using a map of objects and you need to drop one of the keys

Answer (score 106):

If you're using jquery:

```
$.extend({}, ['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

Comment: Weird, if I give in an Array variable it puts every character in a separate object: 0: "a", 1: ",", 2: "b"... So it ignores the quotes, but includes the commas...

Comment: @Max I think there is no such behavior. The returned object is `{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}` what is an expected result.

Comment: Is there a way to use $.extend while also informing the keys in a non-numerical manner, ie: making calcultations on the array items?

Answer (score 76):

For completeness, ECMAScript 2015(ES6) spreading. Will require either a transpiler(Babel) or an environment running at least ES6.

```js
console.log(
   { ...['a', 'b', 'c'] }
)
```

Comment: Actually this isn't natively available in ES2015 either. It is very elegant however.

Comment: how to get result - { "a": "a", "b":"b", "c":"c" } using spread?

Comment: [available in ES2018](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals)

Answer (score 60):

In case you want to use one of the properties of the iterated objects as key, for example:

```
// from:
const arr = [
    {
        sid: 123,
        name: 'aaa'
    },
    {
        sid: 456,
        name: 'bbb'
    },
    {
        sid: 789,
        name: 'ccc'
    }
];
// to:
{
  '123': { sid: 123, name: 'aaa' },
  '456': { sid: 456, name: 'bbb' },
  '789': { sid: 789, name: 'ccc' }
}
```

Use:

```
const result = arr.reduce((obj, cur) => ({...obj, [cur.sid]: cur}), {})
```

Comment: I am wondering how fast this reduce thing is. In each iteration the object is cloned again and again with spread operator?

Answer (score 55):

Not many people here commented of [**`Object.fromEntries`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), I really enjoy it, since it's cleaner and works easily with **TypeScript**, without bothering too much about generic types and stuff. It also allows custom keys with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), if needed. Cons: you'll need an additional `map`, if you want a custom key. E.g.:

```js
const tags = [
  { name: 'AgeGroup', value: ageGroup },
  { name: 'ApparelTypes', value: apparelTypes },
  { name: 'Brand', value: brand },
  // ...
]

const objectTags = Object.fromEntries(tags.map((t) => [t.name, t.value]))

/*
{
  AgeGroup: 'Adult',
  Apparel: 'Creeper, Jacket'
  Brand: '',
  // ...
}
*/
```

Answer (score 48):

I'd probably write it this way (since very rarely I'll not be having the underscorejs library at hand):

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
var obj = _.extend({}, a);
console.log(obj);
// prints { '0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': 'c' }
```

Comment: you downvote my response, but no comment?  My answer is correct and tested.  What is the objection?

Comment: This question has no underscore tag, and you are also assuming node.js or a require library.

Comment: underscore is pretty common on both client and server.  It's assumed for Backbone.js and is probably THE most common utility library.  That being said, I included the require line to make it clear I was using a library.  There's no 1-liner for describing "add underscore.js to your page", so some translation is required for a browser environment

Comment: Still, if you’re using undserscore, a simple `obj=_.extend({},a);` would do the job. Also, if you are iterating through arrays I’d say `_.each` would be more appropriate than `_.map`. All in all, this is not a good answer on several levels.

Comment: Your suggestion to use _.extend is a good one.  I didn't realize that would work on an array.  Normally I prefer 'map' to 'each' because perf micro-optimization aside, 'map' can accomplish everything that 'each' accomplishes, reducing by 1 the number of methods I need to think about.... that's one of my few complaints about underscore, having too many methods where a smaller canonical set would suffice.  JS1.6 seems to agree with me, defining a built in 'map', but no 'each' method.

Comment: Using underscore and Backbone and this solved my problem perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @CharlieMartin that analogy is completely flawed, because lodash, underscore, and jQuery are not "standard libraries" and, in a great number of JavaScript use cases, adding libraries directly impacts end users, which one should not do for trivial reasons.

Comment: @morewry I was trying to suggest that they should be in the standard libraries in javascript. Not that they are. `_.extend` was added to the standard libraries in ECMA 6 as `Object.assign` anyway

Answer (score 31):

we can use `Object.assign` and `array.reduce` function to convert an Array to Object.

```js
var arr = [{a:{b:1}},{c:{d:2}}] 
var newObj = arr.reduce((a, b) => Object.assign(a, b), {})

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I didn't need the indeces, I needed to transform the array into retained key-value pairs.

Comment: plus one for the KungFu, I need it for conversion of `arr = [{ b: 1, d: 2 }]` to obj.

Answer (score 27):

Here is an O(1) ES2015 method just for completeness.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // array, already an object
Object.setPrototypeOf(arr, Object.prototype); // now no longer an array, still an object
```

Comment: (1) According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf), changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is a very slow operation. (2) This does not remove the own `length` property. (3) The object is still an array, `Array.isArray(arr) === true`. (4) Special array behaviors are not removed, e.g. `arr.length = 0` removes all indices. (5) [Therefore, I think `Object.assign` is much better](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36388401/1529630).

Comment: @Oriol mdn is wrong, at least in V8 (but also other engines) this is a pretty fast operation in this particular case - since objects have a numerical store anyway this is basically changing two pointers.

Comment: This also can be used for the fact that it is apparently unique among the other quick solutions, of preserving any non-index ("own") properties on the array (i.e., non-positive-integer properties)...

Comment: But hmm, `Array.isArray` is returning `true` for the "object" here even though `instanceof Array` does not...

Comment: @BrettZamir that sounds like a bug :D

Answer (score 18):

FWIW, one another recent approach is to use the new `Object.fromEntries` along with `Object.entries` as follows:

```
const arr = ['a','b','c'];
arr[-2] = 'd';
arr.hello = 'e';
arr.length = 17;
const obj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(arr));
```

...which allows for avoiding storing sparse array items as `undefined` or `null` and preserves non-index (e.g., non-positive-integer/non-numeric) keys.

> { 0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", "-2": "d", hello: "e" }

(Same result here as with @Paul Draper's `Object.assign` answer.)

One may wish to add `arr.length`, however, as that is not included:

```
obj.length = arr.length;
```

Comment: you can use `arr.entries()` instead of `Object.entries(arr)`

Answer (score 17):

If your array contains **2-element arrays** where first element is the key and second element is the value you can easily convert to object using `reduce`.

```js
[
  ["key1","value1"], 
  ["key2", "value2"], 
  ["key3", "value3"]
]
.reduce((acc, [key, value])=>({...acc, [key]: value}), {});
```

Result:

```
{  
  key1: 'value1',   
  key2: 'value2', 
  key3: 'value3'  
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Using  [`javascript#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) one can do this

```
var result = {},
    attributes = ['a', 'b','c'];

attributes.forEach(function(prop,index) {
  result[index] = prop;
});
```

With ECMA6:

```
attributes.forEach((prop,index)=>result[index] = prop);
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're using ES6, you can use Object.assign and the spread operator

```
{ ...['a', 'b', 'c'] }
```

If you have nested array like

```
var arr=[[1,2,3,4]]
Object.assign(...arr.map(d => ({[d[0]]: d[1]})))
```

Comment: Not only are your variable names different, but your example will not work, creating a map from the constructor initially requires 2d key-value Array. `new Map([['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']]);`

Answer (score 9):

The shortest answer: (using destructuring)

```
const obj = { ...input }
```

Example:

```
const inputArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
const outputObj = { ...inputArray }
```

Answer (score 6):

A quick and dirty one:

```
var obj = {},
  arr = ['a','b','c'],
  l = arr.length; 

while( l && (obj[--l] = arr.pop() ) ){};
```

Comment: I think you forgot to test that; it produces `{0:"c", 1:"b", 2:"a"}`. You either want `unshift` instead of `pop` or (better) start with `i=arr.length-1` and decrement instead.

Comment: yeah.. just changed it, but then it become less interesting :/

Comment: Could even do `l = arr.length`, and then `while (l && (obj[--l] = arr.pop())){}` (I realize this is old, but why not simplify it even further).

Comment: Is it faster then the other solutions?

Answer (score 6):

Quick and dirty #2:

```
var i = 0
  , s = {}
  , a = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

while( i < a.length ) { s[i] = a[i++] };
```

Comment: Why are you using comma notation?

Comment: Personal preference to have the comma leading on the next line. I find this notation easier to read.

Comment: The loop will stop if the array contains a falsy value. You should check `i < a.length` instead of `a[i]`.

Answer (score 6):

**More browser supported** and **more flexible** way of doing that is using a normal **loop**, something like:

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
obj = {};

for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   obj[i] = arr[i];
}
```

But also the modern way could be using the **spread operator**, like:

```
{...arr}
```

Or **Object assign**:

```
Object.assign({}, ['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

Both will **return**:

```
{0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"}
```

Answer (score 6):

Why No One try this? in ES6

```
let arr = ['a','b','c']
let {...obj} = arr
console.log(obj) //  {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

```
let {...obj2} = ['a','b','c']
console.log(obj2) //  {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

is Very simple way?

Comment: Rather than just criticizing other answers for not trying something, you can explain what advantages your answer has or how it differs from the top answer using "spread syntax". Hint: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property.

Comment: how to make keys is value ?

Answer (score 5):

A simple and cheeky method of quickly converting an Array of items in to an Object

```
function arrayToObject( srcArray ){
    return  JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( srcArray ) );
}
```

Then using it like so...

```
var p = [0,2,3,'pork','pie',6];
obj = new arrayToObject( p );
console.log( obj[3], obj[4] )
// expecting `pork pie`
```

Output:

```
pork pie
```

Checking the type:

```
typeof obj
"object"
```

AND things wouldn't be complete if there wasn't a prototype method

```
Array.prototype.toObject =function(){
    return  JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( this ) );
}
```

Using like:

```
var q = [0,2,3,'cheese','whizz',6];
obj = q.toObject();
console.log( obj[3], obj[4] )
// expecting `cheese whizz`
```

Output:

```
cheese whizz
```

*NOTE that there is no naming routine, so if you want to have specific names, then you will need to continue using the existing methods below.

---

Older method

This allows you to generate from an array an object with keys you define in the order you want them.

```
Array.prototype.toObject = function(keys){
    var obj = {};
    var tmp = this; // we want the original array intact.
    if(keys.length == this.length){
        var c = this.length-1;
        while( c>=0 ){
            obj[ keys[ c ] ] = tmp[c];
            c--;
        }
    }
    return obj;
};

result = ["cheese","paint",14,8].toObject([0,"onion",4,99]);
```

`console.log(">>> :" + result.onion);` will output "paint", the function has to have arrays of equal length or you get an empty object.

Here is an updated method

```
Array.prototype.toObject = function(keys){
    var obj = {};
    if( keys.length == this.length)
        while( keys.length )
            obj[ keys.pop() ] = this[ keys.length ];
    return obj;
};
```

Comment: This destroys both the keys array content and, despite the internal comment, also the values array (its contents). JavaScript works differently than PHP with JavaScript automatically acting by reference on the properties of an object/array.

Comment: No it doesn't, the routine makes copies, the original is not touched.

Comment: Yes, the original is touched. See http://jsfiddle.net/bRTv7/ . The array lengths end up both being 0.

Comment: Ok, the edited version I just changed it with does not destroy the arrays, find that strange that it should have done that.

Comment: `var tmp = this;` had just made a reference, not a copy, as with the keys array you had passed into the function. As mentioned, JavaScript works differently than PHP. I also fixed your current function's while loop condition to be `>=0` instead of `>0` because otherwise you would avoid including the first item in the array (at the 0 index).

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/WpM3h/ for your latest version before my modification: http://jsfiddle.net/WpM3h/

Comment: Updated method that should be supported in older browsers as JSON has been around longer than ECMA added new code features

Answer (score 4):

```
.reduce((o,v,i)=>(o[i]=v,o), {})
```

[docs]

or more verbose

```
var trAr2Obj = function (arr) {return arr.reduce((o,v,i)=>(o[i]=v,o), {});}
```

or

```
var transposeAr2Obj = arr=>arr.reduce((o,v,i)=>(o[i]=v,o), {})
```

shortest one with vanilla JS

```
JSON.stringify([["a", "X"], ["b", "Y"]].reduce((o,v,i)=>{return o[i]=v,o}, {}))
=> "{"0":["a","X"],"1":["b","Y"]}"
```

some more complex example

```
[["a", "X"], ["b", "Y"]].reduce((o,v,i)=>{return o[v[0]]=v.slice(1)[0],o}, {})
=> Object {a: "X", b: "Y"}
```

even shorter (by using `function(e) {console.log(e); return e;}` === `(e)=>(console.log(e),e)`)

```
 nodejs
> [[1, 2, 3], [3,4,5]].reduce((o,v,i)=>(o[v[0]]=v.slice(1),o), {})
{ '1': [ 2, 3 ], '3': [ 4, 5 ] }
```

[/docs]

Comment: What did you intend with `[/docs]`? It would be more useful to make the code snippets executable.

Answer (score 4):

As of Lodash 3.0.0 you can use [_.toPlainObject](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#toPlainObject)

```js
var obj = _.toPlainObject(['a', 'b', 'c']);
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can use `Map` or `Object.assign`, it's very easy.

Create an array:

```
const languages = ['css', 'javascript', 'php', 'html'];
```

The below creates an object with index as keys:

```
Object.assign({}, languages)
```

Replicate the same as above with Maps

Converts to an index based object `{0 : 'css'}` etc...

```
const indexMap = new Map(languages.map((name, i) => [i, name] ));
indexMap.get(1) // javascript
```

Convert to an value based object `{css : 'css is great'}` etc...

```
const valueMap = new Map(languages.map(name => [name, `${name} is great!`] ));
valueMap.get('css') // css is great
```

Comment: Note you can do: Object.fromEntries(valueMap) to convert the map to an object

Answer (score 3):

Here's a recursive function I just wrote. It's simple and works well.

```
// Convert array to object
var convArrToObj = function(array){
    var thisEleObj = new Object();
    if(typeof array == "object"){
        for(var i in array){
            var thisEle = convArrToObj(array[i]);
            thisEleObj[i] = thisEle;
        }
    }else {
        thisEleObj = array;
    }
    return thisEleObj;
}
```

Here's an example ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GjJcH/1/)):

```
var array = new Array();
array.a = 123;
array.b = 234;
array.c = 345;
var array2 = new Array();
array2.a = 321;
array2.b = 432;
array2.c = 543;
var array3 = new Array();
array3.a = 132;
array3.b = 243;
array3.c = 354;
var array4 = new Array();
array4.a = 312;
array4.b = 423;
array4.c = 534;
var array5 = new Array();
array5.a = 112;
array5.b = 223;
array5.c = 334;

array.d = array2;
array4.d = array5;
array3.d = array4;
array.e = array3;


console.log(array);

// Convert array to object
var convArrToObj = function(array){
    var thisEleObj = new Object();
    if(typeof array == "object"){
        for(var i in array){
            var thisEle = convArrToObj(array[i]);
            thisEleObj[i] = thisEle;
        }
    }else {
        thisEleObj = array;
    }
    return thisEleObj;
}
console.log(convArrToObj(array));
```

Results:
[image: Recursive Array to Object]

Comment: Works really well. Thanks

Comment: This should be higher up, if you have `['a' = '1', 'b' = '2', 'c' = '3']` and want it like `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}` this works perfect.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this simply with `Array.of()`. [Array of has the ability to use it's context as a constructor.](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.of)

> NOTE 2 The of function is an intentionally generic factory method; it
>   does not require that its this value be the Array constructor.
>   Therefore it can be transferred to or inherited by other constructors
>   that may be called with a single numeric argument.

So we may bind `Array.of()` to a function and generate an array like object.

```js
function dummy(){};
var thingy = Array.of.apply(dummy,[1,2,3,4]);
console.log(thingy);
```

By utilizing `Array.of()` [one can even do array sub-classing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39996323/4543207).

Answer (score 3):

```js
let i = 0;
let myArray = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];

const arrayToObject = (arr) =>
    Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(item => ({[i++]: item})));

console.log(arrayToObject(myArray));
```

Or use

```js
myArray = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]
console.log({...myArray})
```

Answer (score 3):

**ES5 - Solution:**

Using **Array** prototype function **'push'** and **'apply'** you can populate the object with the array elements.

```js
var arr = ['a','b','c'];
var obj = new Object();
Array.prototype.push.apply(obj, arr);
console.log(obj);    // { '0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': 'c', length: 3 }
console.log(obj[2]); // c
```

Comment: What if I want to convert to `{ name: a, div :b, salary:c}`

Answer (score 3):

Try using reflect to copy from array item to object.

```
var arr =['aa:23','bb:44','cc:55']
    var obj ={}
    arr.forEach(e => {
        var ee = e.split(':')
        Reflect.set(obj,ee[0],ee[1])
    });
    console.log(obj) // { aa: '23', bb: '44', cc: '55' }
```

Answer (score 3):

If someone is searching for a Typescript method, i wrote this:

```
const arrayToObject = <T extends Record<K, any>, K extends keyof any>(
  array: T[] = [],
  getKey: (item: T) => K,
) =>
  array.reduce((obj, cur) => {
    const key = getKey(cur)
    return ({...obj, [key]: cur})
  }, {} as Record<K, T>)
```

It will:

1. enforce first param to be array of objects
2. help to select the key
3. enforce the key to be an key of all array items

Example:

```
// from:
const array = [
    { sid: 123, name: 'aaa', extra: 1 },
    { sid: 456, name: 'bbb' },
    { sid: 789, name: 'ccc' }
];
// to:
{
  '123': { sid: 123, name: 'aaa' },
  '456': { sid: 456, name: 'bbb' },
  '789': { sid: 789, name: 'ccc' }
}
```

usage:

```
const obj = arrayToObject(array, item => item.sid) // ok
const obj = arrayToObject(array, item => item.extra) // error
```

[Here's a demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAngFRAeQEYCsCmwsAvDADxoz4AeU%20YAJhDAEqEgINkDSANPGBQA%20ftyq16TGAGt8KEADMBwgBQBYAFAx4SVAC4YaANoBdGKVO9N2gOb4o3OQZUBLOgFsDaAJTmhMPk1fYiFrHWQUADoEfAYAV2B8FRUQPH5gOIRg-wBvMO1QSFhZFHMYOwc5FQys-JgYqEywGBUcyPbU3H4jEpMDGoBfbzCB-hyB%20GY2UE4efjQhYY1NQuhw1DKjHJgXBgMARgAmAGYAFhhRmG3dgwAiI%20Pb-jgoOAMAcn33i7GdvZhDhcTCtwGtOmVEBEMDgCEQVJDUPx8AAbPxUZGRXZLVYgZH4SLIkA2VqdIZAA).

Comment: This is nice and easily modified to meet other reqs

Comment: Excellent little solution, works like a charm! How to change the output into '123': 'aaa' as per your example?

Comment: Modified function for anyone looking to do what I needed: const arrayToObject = <T extends Record<K, any>, K extends keyof any>(
  array: T[] = [],
  getKey: (item: T) => K,
) =>
  array.reduce((obj, cur) => {
    const key = getKey(cur)
    return ({...obj, [key]: Object.entries(cur).reduce((str, [p, val]) => {
        return `${val}`;
    }, '') })
  }, {} as Record<K, T>);

Comment: Does not work with Date types. Try adding a new property of type Date, then select it

Answer (score 2):

You could use a function like this:

```
var toObject = function(array) {
    var o = {};
    for (var property in array) {
        if (String(property >>> 0) == property && property >>> 0 != 0xffffffff) {
            o[i] = array[i];
        }
    }
    return o;
};
```

This one should handle sparse arrays more efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

If you like oneliners, and IE8 is not a problem anymore (as it should be)

```
['a','b','c'].reduce((m,e,i) => Object.assign(m, {[i]: e}), {});
```

Go ahead and try it on the browser console

It coult be more verbose like this:

```
['a','b','c'].reduce(function(memo,elm,idx) {
    return Object.assign(memo, {[idx]: elm});
}, {});
```

But still rules out IE8. If IE8 is a must, then you can use lodash/underscore like that:

```
_.reduce(['a','b','c'], function(memo,elm,idx) {
    return Object.assign(memo, {[idx]: elm});
}, {})
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not directly relevant but I came here searching for a one liner for merging nested objects such as

```
const nodes = {
    node1: {
        interfaces: {if1: {}, if2: {}}
    },
    node2: {
        interfaces: {if3: {}, if4: {}}
    },
    node3: {
        interfaces: {if5: {}, if6: {}}
    },
}
```

The solution is to use a combination of reduce and object spread:

```
const allInterfaces = nodes => Object.keys(nodes).reduce((res, key) => ({...res, ...nodes[key].interfaces}), {})
```

Comment: Also, `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(nodes).map(([key, value] => [key, value.interfaces]))`

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to do this is the following:

```
const arr = ['a','b','c'];
let obj = {}

function ConvertArr(arr) { 
 if (typeof(arr) === 'array') {
 Object.assign(obj, arr);
}
```

This way it only runs if it is an array, however, you can run this with let global object variable or without, that's up to you, if you run without let, just do Object.assign({}, arr).

Comment: This is the same solution as provided in the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36388401/1974224)

Answer (score 2):

Use the javascript lodash library. There is a simple method 
[`_.mapKeys(object, [iteratee=_.identity])`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapKeys)
 that can do the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in coffeescript

```
arrayToObj = (arr) ->
  obj = {}
  for v,i in arr
    obj[i] = v if v?
  obj
```

Comment: What's coffeescript? We are talking about JS! :D

Comment: It's a little language that compiles into JavaScript :)

Comment: Hmph, it uses strange notation. I like plain JS more.

Comment: @David You could do the entire for loop on 1 line to make the whole thing only 3 lines. :) Example: `obj[i] = v for v,i in arr when v?`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angularjs you can use angular.extend, the same effect with $.extend of jquery.

```
var newObj = {};
angular.extend(newObj, ['a','b','c']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below method would convert array to object with particular given key.

```
    /**
     * Converts array to object
     * @param  {Array} array
     * @param  {string} key (optional)
     */
    Array.prototype.ArrayToObject = function(key) {
       const array = this;
       const obj = {};

       array.forEach((element, index) => {
           if(!key) {
              obj[index] = element;
           } else if ((element && typeof element == 'object' && element[key])) {
              obj[element[key]] = element;
           }
       });
    return obj;
    }
```

For Ex -

[{name: 'test'}, {name: 'test1'}].ArrayToObject('name');

would give

```
{test: {name: 'test'}, test1: {name: 'test1'}}
```

and incase key is not provided as param to the method

```
i.e. [{name: 'test'}, {name: 'test1'}].ArrayToObject();
```

would give

```
{0: {name: 'test'}, 1: {name: 'test1'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use underscore for this, but if that isn't available then I would drop down to using reduce with an initial value of empty object `{}`

```
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce(function(p, c, i) {p[i] = c; return p}, {})
Object { 0="a", 1="b", 2="c"}
```

reduce should be widely available in most browsers today, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: The same solution was already provided in the [second top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4215753/1974224).

Comment: @Cristik it does now, but it didn’t at the time.  It’s one annoying trend now for top answers to copy snippets from bottom answers without providing credit.

Comment: I looked at the revision history before posting the comment, and it showed the edit that introduced the `reduce()` was added on  Mar 12, 2014, which was before your answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to use javascript reduce:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index) { 
   previousValue[index] = currentValue; 
   return previousValue;
}, 
{}
);
```

You can take a look at Array.prototype.reduce(), https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: The same solution was already provided in the [second top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4215753/1974224).

Answer (score 0):

typescript solutioin:

```
export const toMap = (errors: ResponseError[]) => {
  const errorMap: Record<string, string> = {};
  errors.forEach(({ field, message }) => {
    errorMap[field] = message;
  });
  return errorMap;
};

export type FieldError = {
  field: string;
  message: string;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I have faced this issue multiple times and decided to write a function that is as generic as possible. Have a look and feel free to modify anything

```
function typeOf(obj) {
    if ( typeof(obj) == 'object' ) {
        if (obj.length)
            return 'array';
        else
            return 'object';
    } else
    return typeof(obj);
}

function objToArray(obj, ignoreKeys) {
    var arr = [];
    if (typeOf(obj) == 'object') {
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (typeOf(obj[key]) == 'object') {
                if (ignoreKeys)
                    arr.push(objToArray(obj[key],ignoreKeys));
                else
                    arr.push([key,objToArray(obj[key])]);
            }
            else
                arr.push(obj[key]);
        }
    }else if (typeOf(obj) == 'array') {
        for (var key=0;key<obj.length;key++) {
            if (typeOf(obj[key]) == 'object')
                arr.push(objToArray(obj[key]));
            else
                arr.push(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Note that your "typeOf" function is notoriously dangerous - some objects just happen to have a "length" property.  I'd recommend using the methods in [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#isArray), like "_.isArray(obj)".

Comment: just check for obj instanceof Array instead of checking for length

Answer (score -1):

initial array and will convert into an Object with keys which will be the unique element of an array and the keys value will be how many times the perticular keys will be repeating

```js
var jsTechs = ['angular', 'react', 'ember', 'vanilaJS', 'ember', 'angular', 'react', 'ember', 'vanilaJS', 'angular', 'react', 'ember', 'vanilaJS', 'ember', 'angular', 'react', 'ember', 'vanilaJS', 'ember', 'angular', 'react', 'ember', 'vanilaJS', 'ember', 'react', 'react', 'vanilaJS', 'react', 'vanilaJS', 'vanilaJS']

var initialValue = {
  java : 4
}

var reducerFunc = function reducerFunc (initObj, jsLib) {
  if (!initObj[jsLib]) {
    initObj[jsLib] = 1
  } else {
    initObj[jsLib] += 1
  }
  return initObj
}
var finalResult = jsTechs.reduce(reducerFunc, initialValue)
console.log(finalResult)
```

Answer (score -3):

My version array to json in JS. Jusy copy/paste and use it. Isn't this awesome? I love this type of functions I found on StackOverflow.

```
function array2json(arr) {
    var parts = [];
    var is_list = (Object.prototype.toString.apply(arr) === '[object Array]');

    for(var key in arr) {
        var value = arr[key];
        if(typeof value == "object") { //Custom handling for arrays
            if(is_list) parts.push(array2json(value)); /* :RECURSION: */
            else parts[key] = array2json(value); /* :RECURSION: */
        } else {
            var str = "";
            if(!is_list) str = '"' + key + '":';

            //Custom handling for multiple data types
            if(typeof value == "number") str += value; //Numbers
            else if(value === false) str += 'false'; //The booleans
            else if(value === true) str += 'true';
            else str += '"' + value + '"'; //All other things
            // :TODO: Is there any more datatype we should be in the lookout for? (Functions?)

            parts.push(str);
        }
    }
    var json = parts.join(",");

    if(is_list) return '[' + json + ']';//Return numerical JSON
    return '{' + json + '}';//Return associative JSON
}
```

Answer (score -5):

```js
var finalResult = ['a','b','c'].map((item , index) => ({[index] : item}));
console.log(finalResult)
```

Comment: the returns an array of objects. the question was about a single object with index as a key and value as the value.

Answer (score -10):

A more OO approach:

```
Array.prototype.toObject = function() {
 var Obj={};

 for(var i in this) {
  if(typeof this[i] != "function") {
   //Logic here
   Obj[i]=this[i];
  }
 }

 return Obj;
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this approach, 1; you are extending the native prototype. 2; you are using `for in` in an array wich will also loop through static properties of the array. 3; why are you excluding functions?