# Cannot load data in an ExtJS gridpanel with loadData()

Tags: javascript, extjs, store, gridpanel

I need to periodically add new data in the grid's store. The store is defined by the following code:

```
this.reader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        idProperty: 'id',
        fields: this.lesFields
    });
this.ds = new Ext.data.GroupingStore({
        reader: this.reader,
        data: this.leData,
        sortInfo: {field: 'dendisc', direction: 'ASC'},
        groupField: 'categorie'
    });
```

When I need to append some new data, I do this using `this.getStore().loadData(this.leData)`. Technically the data does appear in the grid's store, but I see on the display only zeros (in the `int` fields) and blank strings (in the `string` fields). I did some researches in Chrome's console and I found out that the `data` property and the `json` property are not the same in `this.getStore().data`. In `json` there is the array with valid data, but in `data` there are only zeros and blank strings.

Am I missing something? Would the `handleAs:'json'` property save the situation?

Comment: how do you exactly define your data that you try to load?

Comment: The complete path for `data` and `json` properties is `this.getStore().data.items[i]`

Comment: @sra, sorry I cannot post the screenshot. `this.leData` looks like `[ Array[28], Array[28], Array[28], Array[28] ]`.

see [link](http://promitt.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/capture.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not that used to GroupingStores but I think the  Reader expect a json object like `{ Id:0, Name: 'MyName' }` or a Array of such objects and then try to match them against the registered fieldnames. But I don't know what there is in your arrays so this is just a guess

Comment: The reader does recognize the data. see [the console output](http://promitt.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/capture2.png)

Comment: @Giku Yes it reconize that there is data an try to read it, but it seems that the reader is not able to map the data to the corresponding field. So it recognized the data but can not match it, therefore your just get empty records. Now are there JSON objects in your array or are there just values?

Comment: @Giku Never mind and maybe I got you totally wrong but if the content of this => `Array[28]` matches the the images, means that is is just a collection of 28 values, how does the reader know which value belongs to which field... so he just insert a empty record. As far as I know the reader need a json object with `{ field: 'value' }`

Comment: @Giku That's way I ask for more details on your Data that you are trying to load

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, sra. You are right, the reader cannot find the match for the data I'm appending. I searched for a solution in order to transform an array `[...]` to an object `{...}`. I found out a function [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object/4215753#4215753), and I made some modifications in it. Now the data displays just the way it should.

Thanks again sra, have a nice day.

Comment: @Giku perfect! Then you could set your question as answered.

Answer (score 3):

JsonReader requires root to be defined. root points the sub-property which contains the records.

here a sample taken from ext documentation:

```
var myReader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    idProperty: 'id'
    root: 'rows',
    totalProperty: 'totalRows',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id' },
        {name: 'name' }
    ]
});
```

and a sample data to be read:

```
{
    success: true,
    totalRows: 100,
    rows: [  // root
        { id: 1, name: 'Alf' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Ben' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Cod' },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: if everything is ok, you should check your fields definition.