# Convert array to Object by JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var arr=[];
arr['first']='val1';
arr['second']='val2';


var json=JSON.stringify(arr);
var obj=JSON.parse(json);  //obj is array
```

Can I return object {"first":"val1","second":"val2"} ?

P.S.: I read [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object) topic

I'm interested in this way of the function

Comment: Simply [don't use arrays like that](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/). Can't you change the code to `var arr = {};`?

Comment: You are already using `arr` as an object when setting values in this `arr['first']='val'` manner. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to convert array to Object?

Comment: Bergi NO.CAptain YES.

Comment: But in your case `arr` is already an object.

Comment: @MichelPhelps have a look at my ans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If somebody has [abused arrays like that](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/), JSON does not help you. It will only serialize the numeric indices of Array objects, nothing else. Copy the properties by hand:

```
var obj = {};
for (var prop in arr)
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(prop)) // don't copy enumerables from Array.prototype
        obj[prop] = arr[prop];

console.log(obj); // {"first":"val1","second":"val2"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use an array to represent this:

Do this instead:

```
var obj = {first:"val1",second:"val2"};
```

Just define the object directly . Stringify and parsing is not necessary