# Push data into object AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have several checkboxes that you can click on. For every checkbox you click on, an ID, that is connected to the checkbox, is pushed into an array:

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="info in test">
  <td>{{info.stracka}}</td><td>{{info.tid}}</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="{{info.id}}" class="checkboxfisk" ng-click="testa(info.id)">
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.testa = function(id) {   //När vi klickar i de olika checkboxarna, så fyllas arrayen med dessa
        $scope.checkboxes.push(id);
        console.log($scope.checkboxes);
    };
```

After this, I'm supposed to send this array containing the ID's to my backend. However, I want to send this Id's in an Object, instead of an array. How can I "push" data, like I do above, into and Object?

Comment: Why you need to push it as an object?

Comment: For storing data in object, you need to have key. Can this key be random ?

Comment: For simplicity, it would be better that you use array instead of object.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat: Because I want to send it like an object to my backend, not an Array.

Comment: @hasH: The backend I use can only use objects of data from Angular, not arrays, that's why I want to send it like an object.

Comment: By the way, you are missing a closing 'td' tag

Comment: @hasH: How do you mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Array to Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't push data into object. Consider object as an collection of key value pair. For every value you want to store into object, you need a key. That's why I was asking about your server side object.

So, in your case, before storing data into an object, i need a key. So, I have to do this like this

```
var testa = function(id){
     checkbox[id]=id;
}
```

This code would definitely store your keys in the object, but look at this.

```
Object {5: 5, 6: 6}
```

This is really how the values are stored.

If you use array instead, your working would be simplified a lot on server side.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need that but one possible solution is
Add name to your checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{info.id}}" class="checkboxfisk" ng-click="testa(info.id, 'UNIQUE_NAME')">
```

init check boxes to object

```
    $scope.checkboxes = {};
```

then modify you function

```
$scope.testa = function(id, name) {  
        $scope.checkboxes[name] = id;
        console.log($scope.checkboxes);
    };
```

Comment: That don't work, because the code that you provided, only assign a new value to the object. The code are not "pushing" new values the object.

Comment: but then you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly answering your question about "pushing" - since you cannot push to an object, you could convert your array to object just before sending it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object).

```
function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    if (arr[i] !== undefined) rv[i] = arr[i];
  return rv;
}
```

In your example, you would do something like

```
$scope.checkboxesObject = toObject($scope.checkboxes);
```

and then send this new $scope.checkboxesObject.

However, make sure you really are "supposed" to send this to backend as an object.