# How to convert array of string to array of object?

Tags: javascript

```
for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++){
    var item = new Array();
    item = {
        subtitle: arr[k]
    }
}
```

How to convert array of string to array of object am using

```
for(var i in data){
    arr.push(data[i]);
}
```

to get array of strings but need to convert array of strings to array of object.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object

Comment: From where would you get the `i` property name back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) when you want to create a new array from a source one by modifying it's values.

```
var arrayOfObjects = data.map(function (item) {
    return { item: item };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

```
var arrOfStrs = ["1","2","3","4"];

// first way - using the regular for
var arrObj1 = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < arrOfStrs.length; i++)
{
    arrObj1.push({item: arrOfStrs[i]});
}

console.log(arrObj1);

// second way - using for...in
var arrObj2 = [];

for(var key in arrOfStrs)
{
    arrObj2.push({item: arrOfStrs[key]});
}

console.log(arrObj2);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a4ev68y2/).

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have an array of strings like:

```
var arr = ["abc", "cde", "fgh"];
```

you can convert it to array of objects using the following logic:

```
var arrOfObjs = new Array(); //this array will hold the objects
var obj = {};   //declaring an empty object
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){  //loop will run for 3 times
    obj = {}; //renewing the object every time to avoid collision
    obj.item = arr[i];  //setting the object property item's value
    arrOfObjs.push(obj);  //pushing the object in the array
}

alert(arrOfObjs[0].item);  //abc
alert(arrOfObjs[1].item);  //cde
alert(arrOfObjs[2].item);  //fgh
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/9ndyb8sx/)**

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrOfStrs = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

var data = Object.entries(arrOfStrs).map(([key, value]) => ({
  [key]: value
}))
console.log(data)
```