# Convert an Array to object with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want build a structure like in the image below

[image]

But I need some help, look how far I did (don't worry about the names, the poblem is the Array)

[image]

I tryied the solution that I saw in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object) to convert an array to object but, without success, like you can see in the image below.

[image]

**MY CODE**

```
    for (index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
        if (result[index].Parent_Id == 0) {

            // Remove all white spaces from my Text.
            var nome = result[index].Texto.replace(/ /g, '');

            // Add a new component.
            newMenu[nome] = {
                name: result[index].Texto,
                type: "item"
            };
        }
    }

    self.tree_data.push(newMenu);
    self.treeDataSource2 = new DataSourceTree({ data: self.tree_data });
```

How can I do a structure like the first image ? The `_data` in first image is a Object.

**

Comment: use array.reduce for the conversion as specified in the link

Comment: Where do you define `self.tree_data`?  It looks to be an array, since you are doing `self.tree_data.push()`.  You need to declare it an object (`self.tree_data = {};`), then do `self.tree_data['prop'] = newMenu;`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thank you, it clarifies for me, I thought that a variable with {} will be an array also.

Comment: `var x = [];` is an array, `var y = {};` is an object.  They behave differently.