# how to convert an array of objects to a collection of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I hope I'm asking the right question.

I have an array like this:

```
var arr = [{item: 1}, {item: 2}, {item: 3}];
```

I need to convert it to an object collection that looks like this:

```
{item1: {item: 1}, item2:{item:2}, item3:{item:3}}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: That't not valid JavaScript.

Comment: As others have said - that's not valid, but why do you think you need an object that looks like that? Are you trying to use it with another method you read about?

Comment: And this is where you explain *why* you (feel that you) have to convert your array of objects to an object of objects...

Comment: @CurlyFro I think you mean something like this: {item: 1, item: 2, item: 3}

Comment: i see my mistake.  the result should like like this: {item1: {item: 1}, item2:{item:2}, item3:{item:3}}.  thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object

Comment: @CurlyFro: What would you need that for? This is a really odd format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over `arr` and add the objects to an object.

```
var arr = [{item: 1}, {item: 2}, {item: 3}];
var obj = {};

for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++){
    obj['item'+i] = arr[i];
}
```

I'd suggest leaving this structure as an array unless you have a *reason* to have it be an object.