# Array of object from array of string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings. I want to convert it to an array of objects.

For example:

```
var x =['one','two','three'];
```

Is there way to convert it array of objects?

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: `x =['one','two','three'];` is not object, but array. `x ={'one': 'one','two': 'thwo','three': 'tree'};` is object (strings in keys)

Comment: Please clarify what the object should look like

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Array to Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with.

```
   function toObject(arr) {
      var rv = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
        if (arr[i] !== undefined) rv[i] = arr[i];
      return rv;
    }
```

Comment: Array of objects, not just object

Answer (score 0):

This returns an object with a property strings which is the array you pass in

```
function convertArrayToObject (array) {
  var obj = {
    "strings": array
  }
  return obj
}
```