# Length of subclassed array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the following snippets the subclassed array behaves differently from original arrays. Why?

```
function Arr() {}
Arr.prototype = new Array();

var iArr = new Arr();    
iArr[0] = 9;
iArr[5] = 10;
console.log(iArr.length);
console.log(iArr[0]);
console.log(iArr[5]);
iArr.push(87);
console.log(iArr.length);
console.log(iArr[0]);
console.log(iArr[5]);
```

results in

```
0
9
10
1
87
10
```

while

```
var iArr = new Array();
iArr[0] = 9;
iArr[5] = 10;
console.log(iArr.length);
console.log(iArr[0]);
console.log(iArr[5]);
iArr.push(87);
console.log(iArr.length);
console.log(iArr[0]);
console.log(iArr[5]);
```

gives

```
6
9
10
7
9
10
```

what I would have expected for the first snippet as well.

I cannot understand why the length property in the first snippet does not change through accessing elements by index.

Comment: [You can't subclass array in ES5](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/)

Comment: What does this mean in this case? Undefined behaviour? What about ES6 (iojs)?

Comment: Closely related: [Array subclassing with setPrototypeOf](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27985546/710446)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length` behaviors only work for objects that have been created by the `Array` constructor via `new Array`. that is, `length` auto-behaviors only work for *genuine `Array` instances*. Here, the only `Array` instance you have is `Arr.prototype`, which is `iArr`'s prototype parent. `iArr` was not created by `new Array`, so it does not get the magic `length` behaviors.

Setting values on `iArr` does not manipulate the prototype parent in any way, so your `Array` instance is unmodified, which means that `length` is unmodified.

When you call `iArr.push`, you're not modifying the parent `Array` instance either, but [the ES5 spec for `push`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.7) requires that `push` set the `length` property of whatever object is called on:

> 6. Call the [[Put]] internal method of *O* with arguments `"length"`, *n*, and `true`.

For an example that works, using ES6 techniques, see [Array subclassing with setPrototypeOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985546/array-subclassing-with-setprototypeof/27986285)