# Is array a special case of an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object

I'm working with this code. Now, just for checking, I printed **typeof arr** and it displayed "object" in the console. Although, I declared **arr** as an array in the beginning. Has it been converted to an object?
Here's the code:

```
<script>
function getDomainsOfEmails(text) {
    var arr=new Array;
    var regex= /[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}/g;
    var matches= text.match(regex);
    for(var i=0; i<matches.length; i++){
        arr[i]=matches[i].match(/@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}/);
    }
    for(j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
    console.log(arr[j]);
    }
    console.log(typeof arr);
}
getDomainsOfEmails("vikaskumar2299@gmail.com is not a mail? Is vikas@xmail.com ? No? google.com? sachin@gmail.comsds gmail.com");
</script>
```

Also, I would like to know if it's an object, what are its properties and values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does typeof array with objects return "Object" and not "Array"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996871/why-does-typeof-array-with-objects-return-object-and-not-array)

Comment: Yes, arrays are just (special) objects. Any value that is not a primitive value is an object.

Comment: For the second question, [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Properties_2).

Comment: In JS an array is just a proper object. What makes it different like many other objects is it's constructor function (`Array()`) and it's prototype being by default set with many useful Methods. Positive integer properties designate the keys and their values designate the items of an array. There is a length property as well which is automatically gets updated accordingly through the keys getters and setters (i assume). You can take a proper object and by array sub-classing turn it into an array. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27986285/4543207

Answer (score 3):

Apparently yes according to following results

```
typeof Array()
```

returns `"object"`

```
Array() instanceof Object
```

returns `true`

Update: According to API documents

> All Array instances inherit from Array.prototype. The prototype object of the Array constructor can be modified to affect all Array instances.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Properties_2

Comment: FWIW, `typeof` is a poor solution to get the *real* type of a value.

Comment: Going through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof I see that its actually better to use Array.isArray in your case to differentiate regular objects from arrays. So in this case typeof gives you undesirable result.

Answer (score -1):

yes Arrays are objects only

create an array

var arr = new Array();

arr.____proto____ (proto link stackoverflow is consuming 2 undescores) --> Array.prototype

Array.prototype ---> Object.prototype

Also [1,2,3] instanceof Object ---> true