# ES6 Class extends Array: workaround for ES5 Babel transpile

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-class

I have some ES6 class inherited from `Array`:

```
class Cache extends Array {
  add(item) {
    if(!item.doNotRemove)
      this.push(item)
  }
  printLast() {
    if(this.length > 0)
      console.log(this[this.length - 1].text)
  }
}
```

The following code works fine

```
const myCache = new Cache()
myCache.add({text: 'hello'})
myCache.add({text: 'world'})
myCache.add({text: '!!!', doNotRemove: true})
myCache.printLast() // world
```

But I can't transpile it to ES5 with Babel (I know there is an [issue](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/caveats/#classes)), and currently as a workaround I apply the following approach:

```
const CacheProto = {
  add(item) {
    if(!item.doNotRemove)
      this.push(item)
  },
  printLast() {
    if(this.length > 0)
      console.log(this[this.length - 1].text)
  }
}
function Cache() {
  return Object.assign(Object.create(Array.prototype), CacheProto)
}
```

This satisfies the code above (`myCache = new Cache()` etc). But as you can see, it's just an Array instance extending.

**The question**

Is it possible to have a workaround with **original class**? Of course, without `extends Array`. Is it possible to have `add` and `printLast` methods and all `Array.prototype` methods on the prototype chain, not on instance?

I have made a little [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/efHEj6JyqxEok4FLcDKm) for possible research.

Comment: Do you actually need the fancy behavior of `Array`? None of your code actually looks like extending `Array` is needed.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I actually do. It's just a cut sample.

Comment: @dhilt: What exactly do you need?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27985546/1048572) for the correct approach of extending arrays

Comment: @felix-kling I need to have an access to `myCache.reduce()` and others Array.prototype methods together with `myCache.add()` and other Cache class methods. And it would be better to have `.add` not in instance but on prototype (current answers satisfy this requirement). But which is more important, I would like to have  es6 class as a foundation of "cache" functionality.

Comment: But do you actually want instances of `Cache` be used as arrays? Do you want "callers" to be able to do `cache[42]  = 21;`? Which arrays methods do you want to expose? As I said in my answer, exposing them is not an issue.

Comment: Actually I have faced with this bug today. And I wonder that why tsc or Babel doesn't give any warning or any error? This error looks like known error for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussions here I was able to build a solution satisfied both of the requirements: keep original ES6 class as a state for new functionality and have this new functionality on the prototype as well as it is for the Array.prototype methods.

```
class CacheProto {
  add(item) {
    if(!item.doNotRemove)
      this.push(item)
  }
  printLast() {
    if(this.length > 0)
      console.log(this[this.length - 1].text)
  }
}

function Cache() {
  const instance = [];
  instance.push.apply(instance, arguments);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(instance, Cache.prototype);
  return instance;
}
Cache.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(CacheProto.prototype).forEach(methodName =>
  Cache.prototype[methodName] = CacheProto.prototype[methodName]
);
```

The only difference between this `CacheProto` and the original class from the Question is that the `CacheProto` class does not extend the `Array`.

The end plunker could be obtained [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/6VX2LOL1BbnqYuNBZCnR?p=preview). It contains this solution and all intermediate variants.

Comment: There is no reason not to have `Cache` and `CacheProto` be the same object (constructor function). And there's no reason not to use `extends Array`, even if the default constructor doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You only really have to extend `Array` if you want to the magic `.length`-affecting property assignment (`arr[42] = 21;`) behavior or most of the array methods. If you don't need that, using an array as internal data structure seems to be the simplest (and most compatible) solution:

```
class Cache {
  constructor() {
    this._data = [];
  }

  add(item) {
    if(!item.doNotRemove)
      this._data.push(item)
  }

  printLast() {
    if(this.length > 0)
      console.log(this._data[this._data.length - 1].text)
  }
}
```

You can easily expose `.length` and other methods.

---

An easy way to pull in multiple methods from `Array.prototype` would be:

```
['reduce', 'filter', 'find', ...].forEach(method => {
  Cache.prototype[method] = function(...args) {
    return this._data[method](...args);
  };
});

// Or if you want them to be non-enumerable
// (like they would if they were defined via `class` syntax)
Object.defineProperties(
  Cache.prototype,
  ['reduce', 'filter', 'find', ...].reduce((obj, method) => {
    obj[method] = {
      value: function(...args) { return this._data[method](...args); },
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: true,
      writeable: true,
    };
    return obj;
  }, {})
);
```

Comment: Maybe you are right, and the best way is just to count all necessary Array.prototype methods as a Cache class methods in a way like `reduce(cb, init) { return this._data.reduce(cb, init); }`... but I wonder if this could be done programmatically

Comment: Of course one problem here is things like `instanceOf` , `typeof` etc are not going to work.

Comment: @Keith: `instanceof Array` wouldn't work, yes. `typeof array` returns `"object"` anyway.

Comment: Sorry, yes.. I meant `Array.isArray`.. Anyway, you get my point.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks! The last question... about this white list. Could it be created programmatically? I know that `Object.keys(Array.prototype)` and other would not work.

Comment: @dhilt: You could use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`, but that's probably not supported everywhere. If you actually look at `Array.prototype` there aren't that many methods and it's not like new methods get added all the time. I wouldn't worry about maintaining that list (for now).

Comment: I got it! `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype)` – and it is more compatible against `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the prototype directly using `__proto__`, it's also now kind of been standardised for backward compatibility reasons so should be safe to use.

More info here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

edit: Like @Bergi pointed out, using a shim with `Object.setPrototypeOf` would future proof this technique too.

```js
function Cache() {
  var arr = [];
  arr.push.apply(arr, arguments);
  arr.__proto__ = Cache.prototype;
  //if using a shim, (better option).
  //Object.setPrototypeOf(arr, Cache.prototype);
  return arr;
}
Cache.prototype = new Array;
Cache.prototype.printLast = function () {
  if(this.length > 0)
    console.log(this[this.length - 1].text)
}
Cache.prototype.add = function (item) {
  if(!item.doNotRemove)
    this.push(item)
}



const myCache = new Cache()
myCache.add({text: 'hello'})
myCache.add({text: 'world'})
myCache.add({text: '!!!', doNotRemove: true})
myCache.printLast() // world

myCache.forEach(function (item) { console.log(item); });

console.log("is Array = " + Array.isArray(myCache));
```

Comment: It's standardized *and deprecated*. Please don't use `__proto__` - use `Object.setPrototypeOf` (and a shim for it when necessary).

Comment: @Bergi  Yes, using with a shim would be better.  Showing the `__proto__` as that's what the shim is likely to use.

Comment: @Keith This surely works, but what about class syntax? I'd like to keep Cache functionality in a class. Felix Kling suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46898347/3211932) to encapsulate the array into the Cache instance property (this._data = []) and then extend Cache prototype with Array prototype methods. But if it were possible to avoid this._data and provide a reverse extending, like it is in your variant but based on es6 class methods (and not on separate functions as it is in your try and not on some object methods like in my initial workaround)...

Comment: @Keith Looks like I did it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46900998/3211932. That would not have been possible without your post, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hacky, but I'm pretty sure it does what you are looking for.

```js
function Cache() {}
Cache.prototype = new Array;
Cache.prototype.add = function(item) {
  if (!item.doNotRemove) {
    this.push(item);
  }
};
Cache.prototype.printLast = function() {
  if (this.length <= 0) { return }
  console.log(this[this.length - 1].text);
}

let test = new Cache();
test.add({foo:'bar', text: 'cake' });
test.add({baz:'bat', doNotRemove: true});
test.add({free:'hugs', text: 'hello'});
test.printLast();
console.log(test);
```

Comment: [No, it doesn't](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/)

Comment: @Bergi On your link... Is it possible to have [this approach](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/#wrappers_prototype_chain_injection) but keeping class syntax for base cache functionality?

Comment: @dhilt Yes: `class CustomArray extends Array { constructor() { return Object.setPrototypeOf([], new.target.prototype); } … }`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for participation! Looks like I can't finalize your idea, may I ask you to fix [this new plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6Hf8i16niGECGYoH76Zy?p=preview)?

Comment: @dhilt You forgot `extends Array`, otherwise `Cache.prototype` doesn't inherit the Array methods

Comment: @Bergi After transpiling with Babel, there are no Cache class methods on new Cache instance (as it is in initial issue).

Comment: @dhilt What does it transpile to? This seems to vary a lot between Babel versions and settings. I'll guess that `new.target` doesn't work right, you can try `Object.setPrototypeOf([], Cache.prototype)` instead.

Comment: @Bergi `new.target` works fine, `extends Array` doesn't work. Babel can't simulate extending of native entities (like Array) provided via `class extends` syntax ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33837088/3211932)).

Comment: @dhilt It doesn't need to construct the array (which cannot be simulated indeed), we do that ourselves with `Object.setPrototypeOf([], …)`. All it needs to do is let `Cache.prototype` inherit from `Array.prototype`.

Comment: @Bergi I understand prototype chaining approach, but I definitely can't apply it with `class Cache` syntax. `setPrototypeOf` doesn't work for prototype as a first argument, while calling `setPrototypeOf` with instance as a first argument just overrides the prototype of instance and so it could be Cache or Array, not Cache inherited from Array.

Comment: @dhilt Yes, it definitely should be `[]` inheriting from `Cache.prototype` inheriting from `Array.prototype`. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @Bergi According to your vision ([] --> Cache.prototype --> Array.prototype)  I built a prototype chain, where `Cache.prototype` is being extended with necessary functionality taken from ES6 class prototype (`CacheProto.prototype`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/46900998/3211932. 
Do you find it appropriate?