# Methods undefined when babel transpiled ES6 to ES5

Tags: polymer, babeljs, ecmascript-5, es6-class

I'm having a issue with babel transpile down to ES5. For the majority of my
application *all other classes are compiled down correctly*.
One of the classes however has a problem. When it is transpiled, then none of the methods are present on the instances anymore.

When the class constructor is executed, it raises a exception:

`Uncaught TypeError: this.basket.setCurrency is not a function`

Here is the class.

```
export class Basket extends ItemSet {
  static get currencies() {
    return [
      { code: 'gbp', symbol: '£', title: 'Pounds' },
      { code: 'usd', symbol: '$', title: 'US Dollars' },
      { code: 'eur', symbol: '€', title: 'Euros' }
    ];
  }

  constructor(currency, ...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.store = window.localStorage;
    this.setCurrency(currency);
    this.load();
  }

  setCurrency(code) {
    // Only set the currency if it's valid for our Basket
    Basket.currencies.forEach((currency) => {
      if (currency.code == code) {
        this.currency = currency;
        this.store.cxCurrency = JSON.stringify(this.currency);
      }
    });
  }

  ... <snip> ...

}
```

The class that it's extending, `ItemSet` can be found in `basket-weaver`:

https://github.com/andrewebdev/basket-weaver/blob/master/src/items.js#L72-L80

```
export class ItemSet extends Array {

  getTotal(...args) {
    let subTotals = this.map(item => { return item.getTotal(...args); });
    if (!subTotals) throw "Cannot call getTotal() on an empty ItemSet";
    return sum(...subTotals);
  }

}
```

Finally, here is the code that is being generated by babel when it's
transpiled, just pasting the relevant part for brevity:

```
var Basket =
/*#__PURE__*/
function (_ItemSet3) {
  babelHelpers.inherits(Basket, _ItemSet3);

  function Basket() {
    babelHelpers.classCallCheck(this, Basket);
    return babelHelpers.possibleConstructorReturn(this, (Basket.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Basket)).apply(this, arguments));
  }

  babelHelpers.createClass(Basket, [{
    key: "setCurrency",
    value: function setCurrency(code) {
      var _this7 = this;

      // Only set the currency if it's valid for our Basket
      Basket.currencies.forEach(function (currency) {
        if (currency.code == code) {
          _this7.currency = currency;
          _this7.store.cxCurrency = JSON.stringify(_this7.currency);
        }
      });
    }
  }, {
    ... <snip lots of other methods & properies> ...
  }]);
  return Basket;
}(_items.ItemSet);

_exports.Basket = Basket;
```

Last bit of background: I'm using `polymer build` to do the transpiling
since my components are mostly polymer elements.

Does anyone know what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is because es5 would not let you extend arrays. There are some workarounds which I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46898347/433267

I've implemented this in `basket-weaver` on a special `es5-compat` branch.