# how to sort an array of objects using a related property from objects in second array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

There are many questions regarding sorting with JavaScript but I didn't find anything that addresses this case so I don't believe this is a duplicate.

I'm getting data like this back from an api:

```
//items array 
var items = [{id:1, name:'bill'}, {id:2, name:'sam'}, {id:3, name: mary}, {id:4, name:'jane'}]

//sort order array
var order = [{id:1, sortindex:4}, {id:2, sortindex:2}, {id:3, sortindex: 1}, {id:4, sortindex:3}]
```

How can I sort the items array by the `sortindex` property of the objects in the order array? The objects in the two arrays have the common property `id`. Is there an elegant lodash/underscore solution?

Comment: Is this an API you control? Why wouldn't you just return sorted data? This seems bananas to me.

Comment: @m59 your solution using lodash best answered my question.

Comment: @Mathletics Although I don't have complete control over what is returned from the API, your point to consider looking there is well taken.  This is also just a small piece of a more complex problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's straightforward with lodash. The `sortBy` function will move the items to the `sortindex` position, so we just need to use `find` to get the corresponding object, and return its `sortindex` property for `sortBy` to use.

```js
var items = [{id:1, name:'bill'}, {id:2, name:'sam'}, {id:3, name: 'mary'}, {id:4, name:'jane'}];
var order = [{id:1, sortindex:4}, {id:2, sortindex:2}, {id:3, sortindex: 1}, {id:4, sortindex:3}];

var sorted = _.sortBy(items, function(item) {
  // sorts by the value returned here
  return _.find(order, function(ordItem) {
    // find the object where the id's match
    return item.id === ordItem.id;
  }).sortindex; // that object's sortindex property is returned
});

document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/3.0.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store your order as a map, it's rather straight forward with vanilla Javascript.

```
var items = [{id:1, name:'bill'}, {id:2, name:'sam'}, {id:3, name: 'mary'}, {id:4, name:'jane'}];
var order = {1:4, 2:2, 3:1, 4:3};
items.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (order[a.id] > order[b.id]) - (order[a.id] < order[b.id]);
});
```

Or if you insist on your original data, assuming it's already sorted as you show it to be:

```
var items = [{id:1, name:'bill'}, {id:2, name:'sam'}, {id:3, name: 'mary'}, {id:4, name:'jane'}];
var order = [{id:1, sortindex:4}, {id:2, sortindex:2}, {id:3, sortindex: 1}, {id:4, sortindex:3}];

items.sort(function (a, b) {
    var ai = order[a.id - 1].sortindex;
    var bi = order[b.id - 1].sortindex;
    return (ai > bi) - (ai < bi);
});
```

If you can't assume the data is sorted, see [this question, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object) on how to create a map from your data.

Comment: What if OP cannot change the data structure?

Comment: It's trivial to run over the order array and turn it into a map.

Comment: I agree with you, but do you think it's trivial for OP?

Answer (score 0):

See in demo: http://jsbin.com/qaquzi/1/edit?js,console

```
//items array 
var items = [{id:1, name:'bill'}, {id:2, name:'sam'}, {id:3, name: 'mary'}, {id:4, name:'jane'}]

//sort order array
var order = [{id:1, sortindex:4}, {id:2, sortindex:2}, {id:3, sortindex: 1}, {id:4, sortindex:3}]


var sortedOrder = _.sortBy(order, 'sortindex');

var bb = _.map(sortedOrder, function (i) {
    return i.id;
})

var sorted = [];

for (var i = 0, ii = bb.length; i < ii; i++) {
    for (var m = 0, mm = items.length; m < mm; m++) {
        var a = items[m];
        if (a.id == bb[i]) {
            sorted.push(items[m]);
        }
    }
}

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
var items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'bill' },
    { id: 2, name: 'sam' },
    { id: 3, name: 'mary' },
    { id: 4, name: 'jane' }
];

var order = [
    { id: 1, sortindex: 4 },
    { id: 2, sortindex: 2 },
    { id: 3, sortindex: 1 },
    { id: 4, sortindex: 3 }
];

_(items)
    .indexBy('id')
    .at(_.pluck(_.sortBy(order, 'sortindex'), 'id'))
    .pluck('name')
    .value();
// → [ 'mary', 'sam', 'jane', 'bill' ]
```

Here's what's going on:

- The [indexBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#indexBy) function transforms `items` into an object, where the `id` values are the keys.
- The [at()](https://lodash.com/docs#at) function gets values from the object, **in order**, of the passed in keys.
- The [sortBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy) function sorts `order` by the `sortindex` key.
- The [pluck()](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck) function gets the sorted `id` array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/2L0jc8g8/). If you know that both arrays will match in length and location of id's, then this is a concise solution:

```
_.chain(items)
 .merge(order)
 .sortBy('sortindex')
 .map(_.partialRight(_.omit, 'sortindex'))
 .value()
```

Otherwise, if they aren't guaranteed to be sorted, then the items can be resolved with a map/find/merge.

```
_.chain(items)
 .map(function(item) { 
    return _.merge(item, _.find(order, {'id': item.id})); 
 })
 .sortBy('sortindex')
 .map(_.partialRight(_.omit, 'sortindex'))
 .value()
```