# Lodash sortByOrder with provided alphabet

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, lodash

I need to sort an array of objects by provided keys. Sorting must be case-insensitive and use provided alphabet. For example let's take initial data that looks like this:

```
var notOrdered = [{
  date: "11-12-2015",
  name: "Tomasz",
  age: 50,
  products: "FDGS",
  rate: 500
}, {
  date: "12-11-2015",
  name: "Łukasz",
  age: 54,
  products: "ŁBDGS",
  rate: 110
}, {
  date: "11-12-2015",
  name: "Jan",
  age: 24,
  products: "ŻDGS",
  rate: 1000
}, {
  date: "11-12-2015",
  name: "Łucja",
  age: 18,
  products: "AEBDGS",
  rate: 50
}];

var keys = ["date", "rate", "name"];
var directions = [true, false, true];
var alphabet = '01234567989aąbcćdeęfghijklłmnńoóprsśtuvwxyzźż'
```

So the result I'm looking for is:

```
var ordered = [{
  date: "11-12-2015",
  name: "Łucja",
  age: 18,
  products: "AEBDGS",
  rate: 50
}, {
  date: "11-12-2015",
  name: "Jan",
  age: 24,
  products: "ŻDGS",
  rate: 50
}, {
  date: "11-12-2015",
  name: "Tomasz",
  age: 50,
  products: "FDGS",
  rate: 500
}, {
  date: "12-11-2015",
  name: "Łukasz",
  age: 54,
  products: "ŁBDGS",
  rate: 110
}];
```

Using lodash's sortByOrder function `var ordered = _.sortByOrder(notOrdered, keys, directions)` takes care of sorting using provided keys and directions - one after another. And it works great. What I need now is to use provided alphabet order instead of the default one and make comparisons case-insensitive.

All the chars that are not listed in the provided alphabet should be compared the default way. I cannot use localCompare, because I need to support old IE and mobile browsers.

The question is: can I somehow make lodash's sortByOrder function to use custom alphabet and if so, how to do it?

Comment: you do know thart old IE is officiely no longer supported by microsoft

Comment: I do know that. Unfortunately, my client doesn't care. Anyway, I couldn't make sortByOrder use localeCompare either.

Comment: alright, good luck with finding the solution!

Comment: probaly you can use this .. if this module is whart u are using  _.sortedIndexBy(array, value, [iteratee=_.identity])

Comment: and here is already an answer you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867721/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-using-a-related-property-from-objects-in-second

Comment: By what field do you want to sort?

Comment: @lordkain Could you explain how .sortedIndexBy could help me here? I just cannot relate question from your link to my case.

Comment: @JohannesJander I want to sort by beys provided in `keys` array (`var keys = ["date", "rate", "name"]`) - one after another.