# Convert a two dimensional array into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a two dimensional array, `datas`, that I want to convert to an array of objects.

The keys are in `datas[0]`, I want to extract them, `name`, `child`, and `size`. and then append each attribute to it to get a master object. For some reason it overrides and is only showing one object when I try this?

```
var test = new Object();
for (i = 0; i < datas.length; i++){
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.name = datas[i][0];
    obj.parent = datas[i][1];
    obj.size = datas[i][2];
    test.update(obj);
}
```

I would like the final result to be:

```
[
    {"name": "Billy", "parent":"Ann", "size": "1"},
    {"name": "Ben", "parent": "John", "size": "1"},
     etc...
]
```

The `datas` array looks like:

```
 [["Name", "Parent", "Size"], ["Billy", "Ann", "1"], ["Ben", "John", "1"] ... ]
```

Comment: Did you try just `JSON.stringify(datas)` ?

Comment: @adeneo that returns a a massive string with no key/pairs, I need each array to be an own object I guess?

Comment: Also update is not a function how should I merge the new object once it is created in the loop?

Comment: Can you show an example of the source and the final result?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: JSON **is** generally a string, and most of time a massive one, there are no keys or values to be accessed in a JSON string? Do you really mean that you're just trying to convert an array to an object ?

Comment: Yes I am trying to convert multiple arrays to different objects..

Comment: what does the `datas` array look like? Also, what is it that you expect `test.update` to do?

Comment: I want to make an array of objects I guess.  One array and within it all of the objects of each array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Array to Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: I've updated your question to reflect that it doesn't actually have anything to do with JSON. I've also tried to state your problem a little more clearly and add a bit of formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make an object without properties, so your desired result can't be achieved.

Assuming you want:

```
[
    {"name": "Billy", "parent": "Ann", "size": "1"},
    {"name": "Ben", "parent": "John", "size": "1"},
     etc...
]
```

Try:

```
var test = [];
for(i = 0; i < datas.length; i++){
  test.push({
    name: datas[i][0],
    parent: datas[i][1],
    size: datas[i][2]
  });
}
// do something with test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  {"name": "Billy", "parent":"Ann", "size"="1"},
  {"name": "Ben", "parent": "John", "size" = "1"}
}
```

is not correct json.  curly braces mean - object, object must be presented in key:value form.  There are two possible correct json of this kind:

array of objects

```
[
  {"name": "Billy", "parent":"Ann", "size"="1"},
  {"name": "Ben", "parent": "John", "size" = "1"}
]
```

deep structure

```
{
  "Billy" {"parent":"Ann", "size"="1"},
  "Ben" {"parent": "John", "size" = "1"}
}
```

to generate first variant

```
    var res = []
    for(i = 0; i<datas.length; i++){
      var obj = new Object();
      obj.name = datas[i][0];
      obj.parent = datas[i][1];
      obj.size = datas[i][2];
      res.push(obj);
    } 
    JSON.stringify(res);
```

to generate second variant

```
    var res = new Object();
    for(i = 0; i<datas.length; i++){
      var obj = new Object();
      obj.parent = datas[i][1];
      obj.size = datas[i][2];
      res.[datas[i][0]] = obj;
    } 
    JSON.stringify(res);
```