# How I can convert array to object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, types, type-conversion

I am trying to convert in Javascript an array

```
A=['"age":"20"','"name":"John"','"email":"john@email.com"'];
```

to object

```
O={"age":"20","name":"John","email":"john@email.com"}.
```

How I can do this.
Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Array to Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: I tried :   var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(A);
                    var obj = JSON.parse(myJsonString);
                    console.log(obj);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be straight forward, just iterate and split on the colon

```js
var A = ['"age":"20"','"name":"John"','"email":"john@email.com"'];

var O = {};

A.forEach(function(item) {
    var parts = item.split(':').map(function(x) { return x.trim().replace(/\"/g,'') });
    
    O[parts[0]] = parts[1];
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(O, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks Adeneo for your quick answer, but the object have an additional '' , exemple : '"key"':'"value"'

Comment: Well, that's because you have quotes inside quotes, I've removed them for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the keys are quoted, you can take advantage of `JSON.parse`. You can just make the array a string, wrap it in curly brackets, and parse it.

```js
var A = ['"age":"20"', '"name":"John"', '"email":"john@email.com"'];

var temp = "{" + A.toString() + "}";
var theObj = JSON.parse(temp);
console.log(theObj);
```

Comment: That's clever, +1, didnt' think of that, but it does assume everything is always quoted with double quotes and is valid JSON when stringified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const A = ['"age":"20"', '"name":"John"', '"email":"john@email.com"'];
const result = A.reduce((res, i) => {
    let s = i.split(':');
    return {...res, [s[0]]: s[1].trim().replace(/\"/g, '')};
}, {});
console.log(result);
```