# How to create an object from the elements of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of emails in an array:

```
["gomand@gmail.com", "terry@yahoo.com", "123Yu@gmail.com"]
```

How can I loop through the array and push each email into an object as its own property: The object would look like:

```
{
email1: "gomand@gmail.com",
email2: "terry@yahoo.com",
email3: "123Yu@gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: an object with multiple properties having same name? how would you get values from that? is that a typo?

Comment: @suraj Sorry you are right, that was a typo

Comment: plain ol' object doesn't have a concept of `push`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can convert array to object in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667961/how-i-can-convert-array-to-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var inputArr = ['gomand@gmail.com', 'terry@yahoo.com', '123Yu@gmail.com'];
var outputObj = {};
var i;

for (i=0; i<inputArr.length; i++) {
    outputObj['email'+i] = inputArr[i];
}

console.log(outputObj);
```

Answer (score 5):

one liner:

```
var object = ['gomand@gmail.com', 'terry@yahoo.com', '123Yu@gmail.com'].reduce((r, e, i) => (r['email'+(i+1)] = e, r), {});
```

Comment: `(r['email'+(i+1)] = e, r)` « sneaky, I love it!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```js
var arr = ["gomand@gmail.com", "terry@yahoo.com", "123Yu@gmail.com"];
var emails = {}; 
arr.forEach((e, i) => emails["email" + (i+1)] = e);
console.log(emails);
```

Comment: Doesn't 'i' have the value?!

Comment: @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt No, `i` (the second parameter) is the index. Run the snipped to see that it produces the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this quite easily with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var emails = ['gomand@gmail.com', 'terry@yahoo.com', '123Yu@gmail.com']

var result = emails.reduce(function (o, e, i) {
  o['email' + ++i] = e
  return o
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var ary = [];

function pushToAry(name, val) {
   var obj = {};
   obj[name] = val;
   ary.push(obj);
}

pushToAry("myName", "myVal"); // Here it is for single value u can loop with your array.
```

- Help

Comment: why you put your name at last?

Comment: @SagarV "Publicity"

Comment: @suraj (Hence the use of sarcastic quotation marks around my earlier remark)

Answer (score 0):

This is what [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is made for

```js
const emails = ['gomand@gmail.com', 'terry@yahoo.com', '123Yu@gmail.com']
console.info(emails.reduce((map, email, idx) =>
  Object.assign(map, { ['email' + (idx + 1)]: email }), Object.create(null)))
```

Comment: Just curious, is `Object.create(null)` a style choice?

Comment: @thgaskell see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262809/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-object-createnull-versus and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518328/creating-js-object-with-object-createnull

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution

```js
var emails = ["gomand@gmail.com", "terry@yahoo.com", "123Yu@gmail.com"];
var object = {}; 
emails.forEach(function(value, key){
      object["email" + (key+1)] = value;
});

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj = {};
for(i=0;i<yourArray.length;i++){
propName = 'email' + i;
obj[propName] = yourArray[i];
}
```

I believe this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the updated code attached below

```js
var array=["gomand@gmail.com", "terry@yahoo.com", "123Yu@gmail.com"];

var obj = {
   
};
for (var prop in array) {

obj["email"+(prop+1)] = array[prop];
}
console.log(obj);
```