# How to convert an array of key-value tuples into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
[ [ 'cardType', 'iDEBIT' ],
  [ 'txnAmount', '17.64' ],
  [ 'txnId', '20181' ],
  [ 'txnType', 'Purchase' ],
  [ 'txnDate', '2015/08/13 21:50:04' ],
  [ 'respCode', '0' ],
  [ 'isoCode', '0' ],
  [ 'authCode', '' ],
  [ 'acquirerInvoice', '0' ],
  [ 'message', '' ],
  [ 'isComplete', 'true' ],
  [ 'isTimeout', 'false' ] ]
```

But I can't access data via an array's key, e.g. `arr['txnId']` does not return `20181`. How can I convert the above array of tuples into an object, so that I can easily access data by key.

Comment: We have discussion earlier how to convert an Array to Object, You can  refer it and have a best solution as per your requirement.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object

Comment: Arrays are Objects too. ;-)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

### Update June 2020

ECMAScript 2021  brings [`Object.fromEntries`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.fromentries) which does exactly the requirement:

```js
const array =    [ [ 'cardType', 'iDEBIT' ],
      [ 'txnAmount', '17.64' ],
      [ 'txnId', '20181' ],
      [ 'txnType', 'Purchase' ],
      [ 'txnDate', '2015/08/13 21:50:04' ],
      [ 'respCode', '0' ],
      [ 'isoCode', '0' ],
      [ 'authCode', '' ],
      [ 'acquirerInvoice', '0' ],
      [ 'message', '' ],
      [ 'isComplete', 'true' ],
      [ 'isTimeout', 'false' ] ];
      
const obj = Object.fromEntries(array);
console.log(obj);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

This will do it:

```js
const array =    [ [ 'cardType', 'iDEBIT' ],
      [ 'txnAmount', '17.64' ],
      [ 'txnId', '20181' ],
      [ 'txnType', 'Purchase' ],
      [ 'txnDate', '2015/08/13 21:50:04' ],
      [ 'respCode', '0' ],
      [ 'isoCode', '0' ],
      [ 'authCode', '' ],
      [ 'acquirerInvoice', '0' ],
      [ 'message', '' ],
      [ 'isComplete', 'true' ],
      [ 'isTimeout', 'false' ] ];
    
var obj = {};
array.forEach(function(data){
    obj[data[0]] = data[1]
});
console.log(obj);
```

---

Comment: Looks like new Map(array) solution below is more straightforward

Comment: Or even the answer with the "reduce"-method

Answer (score 104):

As [baao notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32002226/120290), since 2019 you can use `Object.fromEntries(arr)` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)) to do exactly this on all modern browsers:

```js
var arr = [['cardType', 'iDEBIT'],
  ['txnAmount', '17.64'],
  ['txnId', '20181']];

console.log(Object.fromEntries(arr));
```

If that’s not available, my previous solution was to map to an array of key-value objects and combine the objects by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
Object.assign(...arr.map(([key, val]) => ({[key]: val})))
```

Comment: [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) are also used in `{[d[0]]: d[1]}` :)

Comment: `Object.assign.apply(null, arr.map(([key, val]) => { return { [key]: val } }))` is a little easier to read and understand (when spread onto multiple lines).

Comment: What are the dots ...?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor That’s the new-ish “spread operator” https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator. Here it turns the array of one-key objects `[{cardType: 'iDEBIT'}, {txnAmount: '17.64'}, {txnId: '20181'}]` into a list of arguments for Object.assign, so it works like `Object.assign({cardType: 'iDEBIT'}, {txnAmount: '17.64'}, {txnId: '20181'})`, which copies all the later values onto the first object, returning the combined object.

Comment: A similar one-liner (with reduce) which has the advantage of being more chainable: `arr.reduce((obj, d) => Object.assign(obj, {[d[0]]: d[1]}), {})`

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor that is the spread operator in ES6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: `Object.assign(...array.map( ([key, val]) => ({ [key]: val }) ))` — An integration of @Toph's answer and @royhowie's comment.

Answer (score 45):

A more idiomatic approach would be to use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var arr = [
  [ 'cardType', 'iDEBIT' ],
  [ 'txnAmount', '17.64' ],
  [ 'txnId', '20181' ],
  [ 'txnType', 'Purchase' ],
  [ 'txnDate', '2015/08/13 21:50:04' ],
  [ 'respCode', '0' ],
  [ 'isoCode', '0' ],
  [ 'authCode', '' ],
  [ 'acquirerInvoice', '0' ],
  [ 'message', '' ],
  [ 'isComplete', 'true' ],
  [ 'isTimeout', 'false' ]
];

var obj = arr.reduce(function (o, currentArray) {
  var key = currentArray[0], value = currentArray[1]
  o[key] = value
  return o
}, {})

console.log(obj)
document.write(JSON.stringify(obj).split(',').join(',<br>'))
```

This is more visually appealing, when done with ES6 ([rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)) syntax:

```
let obj = arr.reduce((o, [ key, value ]) => {
    o[key] = value
    return o
}, {})
```

Comment: cleaner way to avoid param reassign `const obj = arr.reduce((obj, [ key, value ]) => {
      return { ...obj, [key]: value };
    }, {});`

Comment: Or even avoid the return statement: 
`const obj = arr.reduce(obj, [key, value] => ({ ...obj, [key]: value }), {})`

Answer (score 34):

Use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```
new Map(array);
```

> The Map object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original
>   insertion order of the keys. Any value (both objects and primitive
>   values) may be used as either a key or a value.

This works because the type of your variable `array` is `Array<[key,value]>`. The `Map` constructor can be initialized with an array of arrays where the first element of the inner arrays is the key and the second is the value.

```js
const array = [
  ['cardType', 'iDEBIT'],
  ['txnAmount', '17.64'],
  ['txnId', '20181'],
  ['txnType', 'Purchase'],
  ['txnDate', '2015/08/13 21:50:04'],
  ['respCode', '0'],
  ['isoCode', '0'],
  ['authCode', ''],
  ['acquirerInvoice', '0'],
  ['message', ''],
  ['isComplete', 'true'],
  ['isTimeout', 'false']
];

const obj = new Map(array);

console.log(obj.get('txnDate'));
```

Comment: Don't do this...it's too simple ^^

Comment: @Rick I'm confused here. I just tried this in the console: `array = [['a', 1],['b','two'],['c', [3,3,3]]]` and then `obj = new Map(array);`. However, `obj.a` and `obj['a']` are both undefined. So how does this achieve the objective?

Comment: @abalter See the MDN link in the answer. The Map object provides methods for get/set, as opposed to direct property access with dot or square bracket notation with raw `{a: 1}` style objects.

Comment: @RickViscomi -- Ok. Did not know about Map object. However, I would say that what most people are looking for is to get a regular JS object.

Comment: Not sure what most people are looking for, but the original question is looking for the value `'2015/08/13 21:50:04'` given the property `txnDate` and I think this is the most semantic way to do that.

Comment: @RickViscomi, the question specifies "How to convert an array of key-value tuples into an object"

Comment: @PA. `typeof new Map() // "object"` :)

Comment: @RickViscomi tricky :)
`typeof { array }` returns "object" as well but it would not qualify as an answer, would it?

Comment: If someone can find a way to answer the question using an Array, sure. The way I approach StackOverflow is to answer the intent of the question and not necessarily to restrict myself to the semantics of how the question was asked. Sometimes the asker doesn't even know what's possible so they're unable to ask for it specifically.

Answer (score 15):

```
arr.reduce((o, [key, value]) => ({...o, [key]: value}), {})
```

Answer (score 8):

With [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), you can convert from `Array` to `Object`:

```js
var entries = [
  ['cardType', 'iDEBIT'],
  ['txnAmount', '17.64'],
  ['txnId', '20181'],
  ['txnType', 'Purchase'],
  ['txnDate', '2015/08/13 21:50:04'],
  ['respCode', '0'],
  ['isoCode', '0'],
  ['authCode', ''],
  ['acquirerInvoice', '0'],
  ['message', ''],
  ['isComplete', 'true'],
  ['isTimeout', 'false']
];
var obj = Object.fromEntries(entries);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, just be aware that as of writing this its status is: Draft. And the comment is: Initial definition in ECMAScript 2019.

Answer (score 3):

use the following way to convert the array to an object easily.

```
var obj = {};
array.forEach(function(e){
   obj[e[0]] = e[1]
})
```

This will use the first element as the key and the second element as the value for each element.

Answer (score 3):

ES5 Version using `.reduce()`

```js
const object = array.reduce(function(accumulatingObject, [key, value]) {
  accumulatingObject[key] = value;
  return accumulatingObject;
}, {});
```

Comment: How do I use this?  Sorry, javascript newb, not sure how to call this?

Comment: @PaulKenjora Where it says `const object = array.reduce` ... `array` is the name of the variable with the original array, and `object` is the name of the variable you are assigning the new value to. 

It's already being called, and assigning the value to a new variable `object`.

Answer (score 2):

Short ES6 way with Airbnb code style

Exemple:

```
const obj = arr.reduce((prevObj, [key, value]) => ({ ...prevObj, [key]: value }), {});
```

Answer (score 2):

The new JS API for this is `Object.fromEntries(array of tuples)`, it works with raw arrays and/or Maps

Comment: Provide a code sample combining your suggestion with the code from the user that posted the question to make your answer more useful

Answer (score 1):

easiest way to do it where array is of your JSON data  :

```
var obj = {};
array.forEach(function(Data){
obj[Data[0]] = Data[1]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I much more recommend you to use ES6 with it's perfect `Object.assign()` method.

```
Object.assign({}, ...array.map(([ key, value ]) => ({ [key]: value })));
```

What happening here - `Object.assign()` do nothing but take key:value from donating object and puts pair in your result. In this case I'm using `...` to split new `array` to multiply pairs (after map it looks like `[{'cardType':'iDEBIT'}, ... ]`). So in the end, new `{}` receives every key:property from each pair from mapped `array`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this easily using array reduce in ES6

In this example we create a reducer function and pass an object '{}' as initial value to the reduce function along with the reducer

```js
const arr =    [ [ 'cardType', 'iDEBIT' ],
  [ 'txnAmount', '17.64' ],
  [ 'txnId', '20181' ],
  [ 'txnType', 'Purchase' ],
  [ 'txnDate', '2015/08/13 21:50:04' ],
  [ 'respCode', '0' ],
  [ 'isoCode', '0' ],
  [ 'authCode', '' ],
  [ 'acquirerInvoice', '0' ],
  [ 'message', '' ],
  [ 'isComplete', 'true' ],
  [ 'isTimeout', 'false' ] ];

const reducer = (obj, item) => {
  obj[item[0]] = item[1];
  return obj;
};

const result = arr.reduce(reducer, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj ={'abc':123,'other':566};

// first way
let coll= Object.entries(obj).map(i=>Object.assign({'key':i[0],'value':i[1]}))

results: coll => 
0: {key: "abc", value: 123}
1: {key: "other", value: 566}

// second way
let coll2= new Map(Object.entries(obj))
results: coll2 =? 
//[[Entries]]
0: {"abc" => 123}
1: {"other" => 566}
```