# Javascript: Whats the best way Convert Array into Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

what is the best way to convert:

```
a = ['USD', 'EUR', 'INR']
```

to

```
a = {'USD': 0, 'EUR': 0, 'INR': 0};
```

*manipulating array element as key of objects with value as initially 0.

Comment: Define "best". Shortest code? Best performance? Least opportunities for nitpicking?

Comment: This really isn't enough information to go on. Why can't you do this manually, is this procedural data, is there a consistent value you want assigned to each variable in the object, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002176/how-to-convert-array-to-object-in-javascript) are right for you

Comment: @deceze looking for both in terms of short code and performance.. but the main emphasis is on using best manipulation function(for this condition).

Answer (score 24):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to reduce into a single object.

```js
a = ['USD', 'EUR', 'INR'];

console.log(
  a.reduce(function(obj, v) {
    obj[v] = 0;
    return obj;
  }, {})
)
```

---

Or even simple for loop is fine.

```js
var a = ['USD', 'EUR', 'INR'];
var res = {};

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
  res[a[i]] = 0;

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 17):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```js
var array = ['USD', 'EUR', 'INR'],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(k => ({ [k]: 0 })));

console.log(object);
```

Comment: I think this is missing an object as the first argument? `Object.assign({}, ...a.map(k => ({ [k]: 0 })))`

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var a = ['USD', 'EUR', 'INR']
var result = Object.assign.apply(null, a.map(x =>({[x]:0})));
console.log(result)
```