# Convert array of objects into an object with only values (no index or keys)

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to comvert an array that has key value pairs into a simple object that only has the data (no keys).

I have an array like this...

```
[
  0:{pos: 0, color: "#4a55e5"}
  1:{pos: 0.2, color: "#206bcb"}
  2:{pos: 0.4, color: "#edffff"}
  3:{pos: 0.6, color: "#ffaa00"}
  4:{pos: 0.8, color: "#000200"}
  5:{pos: 1, color: "#000764"}
]
```

I need to convert it so that it is like this...

```
colorStops = {
    0: "#4a55e5",
    0.2: "#206bcb",
    0.4: "#edffff",
    0.6: "#ffaa00",
    0.8: "#000200",
    1: "#000764"
}
```

I guess I need to loop through the array and somehow push the values into the object...

```
colorStops = {};
for(var i=0; i<color.length; i++){
   colorStops[i] = color[i].pos : color[i].color;
}
```

I only included this to better illustrate what I want. Of course this doesn't work and results in an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an array of key-value tuples into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002176/how-to-convert-an-array-of-key-value-tuples-into-an-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this statement `colorStops[i] = color[i].pos : color[i].color;` to 
`colorStops[color[i].pos] = color[i].color;`

```js
var color = [ {pos: 0, color: "#4a55e5"}, {pos: 0.2, color: "#206bcb"}, {pos: 0.4, color: "#edffff"}, {pos: 0.6, color: "#ffaa00"}, {pos: 0.8, color: "#000200"}, {pos: 1, color: "#000764"} ];
colorStops = {};
for(var i=0; i<color.length; i++){
   colorStops[color[i].pos] = color[i].color;
}
console.log(colorStops);
```

You can use `array#reduce` and `object#destructuring` to create your object.

```js
var data = [ {pos: 0, color: "#4a55e5"}, {pos: 0.2, color: "#206bcb"}, {pos: 0.4, color: "#edffff"}, {pos: 0.6, color: "#ffaa00"}, {pos: 0.8, color: "#000200"}, {pos: 1, color: "#000764"} ];
var result = data.reduce((o,{pos, color}) => (o[pos] = color, o), {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var colorStops = {}

for (var i = 0; i < color.length; i++) colorStops[color[i].pos] = color[i].color
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for assigning a key-value pair to an object is `obj[key] = value`. So the updated code should look like below:

```js
var color = [
  {pos: 0, color: "#4a55e5"},
  {pos: 0.2, color: "#206bcb"},
  {pos: 0.4, color: "#edffff"},
  {pos: 0.6, color: "#ffaa00"},
  {pos: 0.8, color: "#000200"},
  {pos: 1, color: "#000764"}
];

var colorStops = {};
for(var i=0; i<color.length; i++){
  let key = color[i].pos;
  let value = color[i].color;
  colorStops[key] = value;
}

console.log(colorStops);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` like this:

```
var obj = arr.reduce(function(res, o) {
    res[o.pos] = o.color;
    return res;
}, {});
```

which can be shortened (using ES6's arrow functions) to:

```
var obj = arr.reduce((res, o) => (res[o.pos]=o.color, res), {});
```

**Example:**

```js
var arr = [
  {pos: 0, color: "#4a55e5"},
  {pos: 0.2, color: "#206bcb"},
  {pos: 0.4, color: "#edffff"},
  {pos: 0.6, color: "#ffaa00"},
  {pos: 0.8, color: "#000200"},
  {pos: 1, color: "#000764"}
];

var obj = arr.reduce((res, o) => (res[o.pos]=o.color, res), {});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

With an array, map would work fine.

```
var colorStops = {};

var color = [
  {pos: 0, color: "#4a55e5"},
  {pos: 0.2, color: "#206bcb"},
  {pos: 0.4, color: "#edffff"},
  {pos: 0.6, color: "#ffaa00"},
  {pos: 0.8, color: "#000200"},
  {pos: 1, color: "#000764"}
];

color.map(function(value) {
  colorStops[value.pos] = value.color;
})
```

As you see, you use bracket notation to create new properties inside the colorStop object.

Comment: `map` is a waste (it returns an array that you don't use), use `forEach`