# How to turn array into object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array which I would like to turn into an object with one twist. I would like to set each key and value of the object to be the value of the index of the array which I am currently on.

```
$('#MoveRight').click(function () {
        var selectedUsers = $('#allUsersDD').val();
        //turn to object
    });
```

selectedUsers is an array

Comment: Array **is** an object.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object

Comment: @PM77-1 Yeah, I know. But how would you have phrased the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with a single loop.

```
var usersObj = {};
for (var k = 0; k < selectedUsers.length; k++) {
    usersObj[k] = selectedUsers[k];
}
```

Comment: This also set the key to be the 1,2 and so forth. However I have changed my code so it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

If you have a js Array of lots of key-value pairs, you can convert it like this:

```
var array = [{key:"one",value:1},{key:"two",value:2},....]

var newObject = {}

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    newObject[array[i].key] = array[i].value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#MoveRight').click(function () {
  var selectedUsers = $('#allUsersDD').val();
  var obj = {};
    $(selectedUsers).each(function (i, v) {
      var key = '_' + i;
      obj.key = v;
  });
});
```

Comment: This also sets each key of the object to be the index of the array. In my question I asked for the key and value of the object to be the value of the array which i loop through