# How to send serialized key of attributes on jQuery UI sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Firstly, I need to send attribute data-name with sorting like this:

```
/sorting?firstname=0&lastname=1&email=2&country=3
```

Here is my code:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true,
    axis: 'y',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('toArray', {
            attribute: 'data-name'
        });
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/sorting'
        });
    }
});
$("#draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
});
```

How to do that?

And secondly, when i dragged item "Drag empty" to the list, I need to send sorting without them. I need to skip them, for. ex.:

```
/sorting?firstname=0&lastname=1&email=3&country=4
```

"Drag empty" is after lastname, then email and country have sorting +1.

Here code sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/3b95e27p/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Array to Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object) Same conversion for this question, just invert the places of the idx and value: https://jsfiddle.net/dxa7asza/

Comment: Why not use the inbuilt serialize option and update your backend accordingly...?