# How convert array data to object array?

Tags: javascript

How can I convert this array to object array(below)?

```
array[4]=
    0: "238"
    1: "259"
    2: "276"
    3: "307" to

var dataset = [ 
  { key: 0, value: 238 },
  { key: 1, value: 259 },
  { key: 2, value: 276 },
  { key: 3, value: 307 }];
```

Comment: This can be done with numerous array looping methods. Please show what you have tried

Comment: Please gohead this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object and look at

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply map the original array to an array of objects.

```js
var arr = [
  238,
  259,
  276,
  307
];

var dataset = arr.map(function(value, index) {
  return {
    key: index,
    value: value
  };
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(dataset, null, 2) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var array = [
  238,
  259,
  276,
  307
];

var dataset ={};
 array.map(function(value, index) {  
    dataset[index]= value
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var obj = array.reduce(function(output, val, idx) {
  output[idx] = val;
  return output;
}, {});
```