# How to turn this array into a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

The following code loops through a JavaScript object and collects only the properties that are arrays:

```
const building = this.building
let panoramaList = []
for (let key in building) {
  const panoramas = building[key]
  if (Array.isArray(panoramas)) {
    panoramaList.push({ [key]: panoramas })
  }
}
console.log(panoramaList)
```

In other words, it takes this:

```
{
  name: '',
  description: ''.
  livingroom: Array[0],
  study: Array[1],
  bedroom: Array[0]
}
```

and turns it into this:

```
[
  { livingroom: Array[0] },
  { study: Array[1] },
  { bedroom: Array[0] }
]
```

However, what I need to produce is this:

```
{
  livingroom: Array[0],
  study: Array[1],
  bedroom: Array[0]
}
```

How to accomplish that?

Comment: you might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object

Comment: Why not just delete the unwanted properties?

Comment: @RobG Could you provide an example code for that?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var output = Object.keys(building).map(function(val){ return { val : building[val] } });
```

For the final output

```
var panoramaList = {}
Object.keys(building).forEach(function(val){ 
  if ( Array.isArray(building[val] )
  {
    panoramaList[val] = building[val];
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I get `key` is not defined in ` building[key]`.

Comment: output should be an object and only arrays hould be inserted as property, not as own object in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Change this :

```
const building = this.building
let panoramaList = []
for (let key in building) {
  const panoramas = building[key]
  if (Array.isArray(panoramas)) {
    panoramaList.push({ [key]: panoramas })
  }
}
console.log(panoramaList)
```

to this :

```
const building = this.building
let panoramaList = {}
for (let key in building) {
  const panoramas = building[key]
  if (Array.isArray(panoramas)) {
    panoramaList[key]=panoramas
  }
}
console.log(panoramaList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Object.keys and try something like this:

```
var input = {} //...your input array
var keys = Object.keys(input);
var result = {};

keys.forEach(function (key) {
    if (Array.isArray(input[key])) {
        result[key] = input[key];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to define `panoramaList` as an object.

This works

```
var arrays = {
  name: '',
  description: '',
  livingroom: ['1','www'],
  study: ['2','sss'],
  bedroom: ['3','aaa'],
  Kitchen: ['4','bbb'],
}    


const building = arrays
let panoramaList = {};
for (let key in building) {
  const panoramas = building[key]

  if (Array.isArray(panoramas)) {
      panoramaList[key] = panoramas;
  }
}
console.log(panoramaList);
```

https://jsbin.com/paqebupiva/1/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Rather than building a new object, you might just need to delete the unwanted properties from the object that you have:

```js
var data = {
  name: '',
  description: '',
  livingroom: [],
  study: [1],
  bedroom: [0]
};

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
  if (!Array.isArray(data[key])) delete data[key];
})

document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```