# ImmutableJS - .toObject() deeply

Tags: immutable.js

How can i convert my all data to object? Ex.:

```
//From
var a = Immutable.fromJS({ formats: ["foo", "bar"]})

a.toObject()
// How returns { formats: ["foo", "bar"] }
// How i need { formats: {0: "foo", 1: "bar"}}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried `a.toJS()` ?

Comment: .toJS() will return the same object that i pass: { formats: ["foo", "bar"]  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer given here: [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

```
var a = Immutable.fromJS({ formats: ["foo", "bar"]}); 
var b = {formats: toObject(a.get('formats').toJSON())}; 
console.log(b); 

function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    if (arr[i] !== undefined) rv[i] = arr[i];
  return rv;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o04btr3j/346/