# Javascript/Node.js: Convert array with sub-arrays into object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array that looks like this

```
var myArray = [
    ['a', 1],
    ['b', 2],
    ['c', 3]
]
```

I want to convert it into an object, it should be equal to below:

```
var myObj = {
    'a' : 1,
    'b' : 2,
    'c' : 3
}
```

What is the easier and safer *(if unexpected input comes)* way to go about it?

Update:
To elaborate more on 'safer', sometimes I might get different input like

```
var myArray = [
    ['a', 1],
    ['b', 2],
    ['c', 3, 4, 5]
]
```

or

```
var myArray = [
    ['a', 1],
    ['b', 2],
    ['c', 3],
    ['d']
]
```

Regardless myObj should be equal to:

```
var myObj = {
    'first-key' : 'firts-value'
}
```

or if 2nd element is not available in sub-array

```
var myObj = {
    'first-key' : ''
}
```

Comment: [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: @KevinKloet Elements in my array are arrays themselves.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _unexpected input_? Strikes me as a very important requirement if it means you need to be able to handle things like `myArray` not being an array or somesuch.

Comment: @tmslnz Subarrays might have 1 element or sometimes more than 2. But I'm only interested in capturing first 2, if it has 1 element, value of key can be just `''`

Comment: @sdkks ok. And do those arrays need to be _flattened_ or `c: [1,2,3,4,5,…]` is an acceptable output?

Comment: @tmslnz I updated the question to make it clearer. Thanks

Comment: So what is result for `['c', 3, 4, 5]`?

Comment: @NenadVracar your reduce solution works for both cases. I tested it just now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

None of the other answers handle unexpected input... The way to do this is with `.reduce()` and type checking.

```js
var myArray = [
  [[1, 2, 3], 'a'], // [1] is valid property name, [0] valid value
  ['b', 2, 5, 2], // [0] is valid property name, [1] valid value
  ['c', undefined], // [0] is valid property name, [1] invalid value
  { prop1: "123" }, // Invalid - is not an array
  undefined, // Invalid - is not an array
  123, // Invalid - is not an array
  [undefined, 'd'], // [1] is valid property name, [0] valid value
  ['e'] // [0] is valid property name, [1] does not exist
];

function convertArrToObj(arr) {
  // check to ensure that parent is actually an array
  if (isArray(arr)) {
    return arr.reduce(function(obj, curr) {
      // check to ensure each child is an array with length > 0
      if (isArray(curr) && curr.length > 0) {
        // if array.length > 1, we are interested in [0] and [1]
        if (curr.length > 1) {
          // check if [0] is valid property name
          if (typeof curr[0] === "string" || typeof curr[0] === "number") {
            // if so, use [0] as key, and [1] as value
            obj[curr[0]] = curr[1] || ""
          } 
          // if not, check if [1] is a valid property name
          else if (typeof curr[1] === "string" || typeof curr[1] === "number") {
            // if so, use [1] as key, and [0] as value
            obj[curr[1]] = curr[0] || ""
          }
          // if no valid property names found, do nothing
        } else {
          // if array.length === 1, check if the one element is
          // a valid property name. 
          if (typeof curr[0] === "string" || typeof curr[0] === "number") {
            // If so, add it and use "" as value
            obj[curr[0]] = "";
          }
        }
      }
      // return updated object for next iteration
      return obj
    }, {});
  }
}

function isArray(val) {
  return val === Object(val) && Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === '[object Array]';
}

console.log(convertArrToObj(myArray));
```

Comment: It will take me a few days to digest this. Many lessons here.

Comment: @sdkks I will go through and comment this so you can see exactly what is happening

Comment: @sdkks Check the updated answer with comments explaining what every line does

Comment: Thanks now makes more sense. My expectation of 'unexpected' has not had a spectrum this broad.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `reduce()`

```js
var myArray = [
  ['a', 1],
  ['b', 2],
  ['c', 3]
]

var result = myArray.reduce((r, e) => {
  r[e[0]] = e[1];
  return r;
} , {});

console.log(result)
```

**Update**: for cases where there is just one element in array (return `''`) or more then two (return array with rest of elements).

```js
var myArray = [
  ['a', 1],
  ['b', 2],
  ['c', 3, 3 ,1],
  ['d']
]

var result = myArray.reduce((r, e) => {
  r[e[0]] = (e[1]) ? ((e.length > 2) ? e.slice(1) : e[1]) : '';
  return r;
} , {});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This does not handle "unexpected input". It does not ensure that each property you are iterating over is an indexed array

Comment: @NenadVracar can you explain your updated answer, what does `[...e]` do?

Comment: Still doesn't account for myArray being heterogeneous, nor non-string/non-integer elements of each sub-array

Comment: @sdkks  That is spread operator but actually we don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [
    ['a', 1],
    ['b', 2],
    ['c', 3]
];

var myObj = {};

myArray.forEach(function(element){
    myObj[element[0]] = element[1];
})
```

Comment: This code makes a lot of assumptions - and does not handle "unexpected input" as the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

just use a forEach to populate myObj :

```js
var myArray = [
    ['a', 1],
    ['b', 2],
    ['c', 3]
];
var myObj = {};
myArray.forEach(x => myObj[x[0]]=x[1]);
console.log(myObj);
```