# for loop efficiency, make two for loops into one

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop

So I have 2 separate 2D array, they are not necessarily the same length, and I want to make an object for each. I made this:

```
var obj1 = {},
    obj2 = {};

    for (var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {

      obj1[arr1[i][1]] = arr1[i][0];

    }  

    for (var j=0; j<arr2.length; j++) {

      obj2[arr2[j][1]] = arr2[j][0];

    }
```

My question is if there is a way to make this with only one loop. Thanks!

Comment: See this Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object

Comment: How big are arr1 and arr2? It might not be worth to do any optimization at all here...

Comment: It's not getting more efficient when you use only one loop. You'd need to use a different *algorithm*

Comment: I agree with @Bergi, no matter how much loops you use, there's still the same number of operations.

Comment: @x-ray it depends on the implementation, i don't use ifs in my answer. Though technically I'm using 2 loops, the number of iterations is optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want here is a function abstraction that removes the *duplication*. There is nothing to make this more efficient (if you meant time complexity, not developer efficiency):

```
function arrToObj(arr) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        obj[arr[i][1]] = arr[i][0];
    }  
    return obj;
}
var obj1 = arrToObj(arr1),
    obj2 = arrToObj(arr2);
```

The loop is still executed twice, but it's only *written once*.

Comment: You, sir, are the real MVP. I expressed myself wrong. I should have written "simplicity" and not "efficiency". This is exactly what I meant. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```js
var obj1 = {},
    obj2 = {},
    length = Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length);  // get max array length

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {                // loop max array length

  if (i < arr1.length) {                          // do check for arr1
    obj1[arr1[i][1]] = arr1[i][0];   
  }

  if (i < arr2.length) {                          // do check for arr2
    obj2[arr2[i][1]] = arr2[i][0];
  }
}
```

[As pointed out, this may be less efficient than 2 separate loops](https://jsfiddle.net/1j3kv2wd/2/),

[Although it also may be more efficient](https://jsperf.com/loop-over-arrays-of-different-lengths)

Comment: How is that more efficient?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's slower regardless of the size of arrays.

Comment: OP also asked for "for loop efficiency"

Comment: Hmmm, then I don't think you can get both efficiency and one loop

Comment: It's possible to reduce the number of loop iterations though. With 2 loops it's `arr1.length + arr2.length`, in my answer it's `Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var obj1 = {},
    obj2 = {};

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length && i < arr2.length; i++) {

    obj1[arr1[i][1]] = arr1[i][0];
    obj2[arr2[i][1]] = arr2[i][0];
}

if (arr1.length > arr2.length) {
    for (let i = arr2.length; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        obj1[arr1[i][1]] = arr1[i][0];
    }
}

if (arr2.length > arr1.length) {
    for (let i = arr1.length; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        obj2[arr2[i][1]] = arr2[i][0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Pete's and eur00t's answers, I suggest this one:

```
var commonLength = Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length);

for (var i = 0; i < commonLength; i++) {
    obj1[arr1[i][1]] = arr1[i][0];
    obj2[arr2[i][1]] = arr2[i][0];
}

for (var i = commonLength; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    obj1[arr1[i][1]] = arr1[i][0];
}

for (var i = commonLength; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    obj2[arr2[i][1]] = arr2[i][0];
}
```

As the question is about efficiency, I made a [jsperf test case](https://jsperf.com/loop-over-arrays-of-different-lengths) to compare the solutions.

Answer (score -2):

```
var obj1 = {},   

for (var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {

  obj1[arr1[i][1]] = arr1[i][0];

}  

for (var j=0; j<arr2.length; j++, i++) {

  obj2[arr2[i][1]] = arr2[j][0];

}
```

Hope this will you

Comment: it is not a one loop.

Comment: Is it not just what OP posted?