# JS: Convert An Array Into An Object Without Indexes

Tags: javascript

i have this array:

```
const array = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]
```

I'd like to convert this array into an object without indexes. How would this be possible?

Comment: Any attempt ????

Comment: Perhaps you should describe a bit more what you want as output (some more details) and explain what you've tried so far

Comment: Maybe using this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4215753/2894798