# Convert array to object wrapped with square brackets [ ]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm already looking in [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) but it looks different. I mean, how i can convert array to object with the square brackets format at the start and end of the object?

Array :

```
['a','b','c']
```

to :

```
[
  {
    0: 'a',
    1: 'b',
    2: 'c'
  }
]
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: I'm very confused as to what you are asking for.... please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Wouldn't this `res = [{...arr}]` solve the issue you're having? Where `arr=['a','b','c']`

Comment: @MikeTung. I'm sorry for make you confused,
i mean convert array to object with the square brackets format at the start and end object like my second example code above.

Comment: just wrap the result of the answers in the almost identical question in `[]` - the question you linked to has answers that result in `{0: 'a' ... etc}` ... wrap that in `[]` and you get `[{0: 'a' ... etc}]`

Comment: @JaromandaX, can you show me how to do that?
I have tried `var obj = arr.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
  acc[i] = cur;
  return acc;
}, []);` i change the {} to [] and the result just `[0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c']`. how can i get `[{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}]`.
Sorry i'm newbie.

Comment: see answer below ... or `var obj = [{...array}]`

Comment: by the way, you won't actually get what you "want" ... because object keys are always strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `toObject` function from the answer you mentioned and wrap the result in an array:

```
[toObject(['a', 'b', 'c'])]
```

Or if you are using ES6+, you can do:

```
[{...['a', 'b', 'c']}]
```

Comment: Thank you for you respond, but can you please show how to do that? i don't understand because i'm newbie.

Answer (score 1):

There is various way to achieve this, try with Array.forEach method ,

```
var orgArrayData = ['a','b','c','d'];
var convertedFormatData = [];
var tempObj = {};
convertArrayElemToObject(orgArrayData);
function convertArrayElemToObject(orgArrayData){
    orgArrayData.forEach((element,index)=>{
        tempObj[index] = element;
    });
};
convertedFormatData.push(tempObj);
console.log(convertedFormatData);
```

o/p -

```
[
  0: {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: "d"}
]
```

i hope, it will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
  const a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  const newObject = Object.assign({}, a);
  console.log(newObject);
```