# How to convert array to array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have

```
let array = ['mango', 'mango_shake','banana', 'banana_shake', 'cherry', 'cherry_shake', 'Strawberry', 'Strawberry_shake', ...n];
```

What i want to do is:

```
let target = [{'fruit': 'mango', 'drink': 'mango_shake'}, 
{'fruit': 'banana', 'drink': 'banana_shake'}, ...n];
```

How can i do it?

Comment: What did you try? A simple loop should work

Comment: How is this array generated? Like Axnyff said, a simple looping structure could do this, but its probably better if you could avoid mixing two different things into a single array in the first place.

Comment: When solving problems like this, it helps to think about how you would solve the problem yourself. If I gave you a list of words similar to your array, what steps would you take to create the list of objects? Write a description in words before you even attempt to write any code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: A simple loop is just fine. I cant avoid mixing because i get from database string. Arsalan Akhtar, i see that post.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply loop through array and create an array of object  like this

```js
let array = ['mango', 'mango_shake', 'banana', 'banana_shake', 'cherry', 'cherry_shake', 'Strawberry', 'Strawberry_shake'];
var res = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 2) {
  var ob = {};
  ob.fruit = array[i];
  ob.drink = array[i + 1];
  res.push(ob);
}

console.log(res);
```

**Note**: This answer assumes the fruit and its corresponding drink are always right beside each other in the array. This will give wrong answers if items are out of order.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over your original array until it is empty and take out pairs and map them to objects:

```
 const result = [];

 while(array.length)
   result.push((([fruit, drink]) => ({fruit, drink}))(array.splice(0, 2));
```

(In case this is your homework: i think it will be harder to explain to your teacher how it works instead of just trying it on your own :))

Comment: **Note:** This answer assumes the fruit and its corresponding drink are always right beside each other in the array. This will give wrong answers if items are out of order.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array to combine every other item

```
let target = {};
array.forEach( (curr, indx, arr) => {
    if (indx %2 == 1) {
        target[arr[indx-1]] = curr
    }
});
```