# I have created a new Array by Object constructor, why it's nature is still array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created a new Array by Object constructor, why its nature is still array

```
myArr = [1,2,3];
var newArr = Object(myArr);
if (newArr instanceof Array) {
  console.log('This to is an array');
}
console.log(newArr);
```

---

[image]

Comment: You might start by reading the relevant part of the language specification, [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-object-constructor).

Comment: if you want to convert array to object see this question, [how to convert array to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: When called as a constructor it creates a new ordinary object. When Object is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it performs a type conversion. thanks RobG

Comment: @AtulKumar—yes, the key is that an Array is [*Type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-object-type) Object (noting that *typeof* doesn't return the Type, good eh?), so `Object(myArr)` just returns *myArr*. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object):

> The `Object` constructor creates an object wrapper for the given value.
>   If the value is not `null` or `undefined`, **it will return an object of a Type that corresponds
>   to the given value**. (adapted)