# Array to object reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

Hello I want to transform array to object

input = [1,2,3]

expected output = {1:1,2:2,3:3}

I tried this

```
const arrToObj = (arr) => {
  arr.reduce((acc, curr, i, arr)=> {
    acc[curr]=arr[i]
  },{})
}
console.log(arrToObj([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
```

but it throws errror in second iteration.
What is wrong and how to make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have tried so far has two problems

The first is serious:

You forgot to return from your accumulating function, so it returns `undefined`.

It throws the second time around because `Array.prototype.reduce` passes the specified seed as the first argument on the first call to the accumulating function but, on the second call, it passes the result of the first call.

So initially, reduce calls your function like this

```
result = accumulatorFunction(seed, arr[0], 0, arr);
```

which expands to

```
result = accumulatorFunction({}, 1, 0, [1, 2, 3]);
```

The subsequent call, however, looks like this

```
result = accumulatorFunction(result, arr[1], 1 arr);
```

which expands to

```
result = accumulatorFunction(undefined, 2, 1, [1, 2, 3]);
```

So you need to write something like

```
arr.reduce((acc, curr, i, arr) => {
  acc[curr] = arr[i];
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Another issue with your code, and more one of style, is that you needlessly provide and use the fourth argument passed to the accumulating function. This argument is just the array itself anyway. Using it is awkward and makes your code more complex, more prone to mistakes, and harder to understand.

Instead write

```
arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = curr;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

```js
"use strict";

const input = [1, 2, 3];

const output = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = curr;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
const obj = arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) => {
  accumulator[index+1] = currentValue;
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Yup, it works but I want to achieve that using reduce

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that i didn't return acc in my code and that was a reason of error

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arrToObj = a => a.reduce((r, v) => (r[v] = v, r), {})

console.log( arrToObj( [1, 2, 3] ) )
```

If the values match the indexes, it can be even simpler with ECMAScript 2018 [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) :

```js
console.log( { ...[, 1, 2, 3] } )
```

Comment: ECMAScript 2018 syntax looks cool in this example. Thanks for answer!

Comment: This is an elegant approach but you linked to the wrong documentation. Array spread is not the same as object spread

Comment: @AluanHaddad it's generic for the spread syntax, so it covers function call, array, and object.