# Fetching from REST API and storing json response for further filtering of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, fetch-api

I've been dabbling with React and REST APIs for app development. I have a WordPress website and am using the WP Rest API. I have successfully fetched all the posts from the category I want. I would like to be able to show different views/filters of the results based on that data, but I would like to not redo the fetch for each filter, since all the data is being retrieved from the very first GET request.

My question is how can I store that JSON response somewhere as an object or something, so that when a user clicks on a filter (for example, display only posts from year 2017) the program will iterate through that object it already fetched once, and extracting only those with year 2017.

Currently I have the functionality that I want, but I am sort of 'hard coding' all the possible list views within the success callback of the fetch. So I create ALL my possible lists and then my buttons just switch back and forth between each list. This doesn't seem that 'correct' to me, I would imagine it's faster not to do all the iterating in one spot but rather when a user selects a filter. Below you can see the code to my module that is handling the request and list displaying. This is made in React.

Any suggestions on how to handle this situation are welcome, even if it ends up being that the way I'm doing it is the best approach!

```
import React from 'react';
import Ebook from './Ebook';


class EbookList extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        allPosts : [],
        revista : [],
        boletin: [],
        filterBy : 'revista'
    }

    this.fetchPosts = this.fetchPosts.bind(this);
    this.filterList = this.filterList.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    //this.renderSomething = this.renderSomething.bind(this);
}
fetchPosts(){

    const url = 'https://cipm.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=15&per_page=50';

    fetch(url).then(response => {
      if(response.ok){
        return response.json();

      }
      throw new Error('Fetch failed');

    },networkError=>console.log(networkError.message)).then(
    responseJson=>{
      
      console.log(responseJson.length);
    
      let postList = responseJson.map(post => {
        // console.log(post.date);
       return <Ebook ebookData={post} key={post.id} />
      });

      let boletinList = responseJson.map(post => {
        //tag 17 is revista
        //tag 16 is boletin
        if(post.tags.includes(16)){
            return <Ebook ebookData={post} key={post.id} />
        } return null;
      });

      let revistaList = responseJson.map(post => {
        //tag 17 is revista
        //tag 16 is boletin
        if(post.tags.includes(17)){
            return <Ebook ebookData={post} key={post.id} />
        }return null;
      });
      let yearList = responseJson.map(post=>{
        if(post.date===2018){
            return <Ebook ebookData={post} key={post.id} />
        }return null;
      })
       this.setState({
        allPosts:postList,
        boletin:boletinList,
        revista:revistaList,
        year: yearList
       });
       // console.log("the state object: " + this.state.jsonObject[0]);
       console.log(responseJson);
       console.log(postList);
      
     
      
    });
}

filterList(){
    if(this.state.filterBy === 'boletin'){
        return this.state.boletin;

    } else if (this.state.filterBy === 'revista'){
        return this.state.revista;
    } else if (this.state.filterBy === 'viewAll'){
        return this.state.allPosts;
    }
}

handleClick(event){
    
    this.setState({filterBy:event.target.value});
}
componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchPosts();
 }


render(){
    // {this.props.dataObject.map(ebook =>{
        //  return <Ebook ebookData={ebook} />
        //  })}
    return (
        <div className="ebookList-container">
            <div className="ebookList-controls">
                <button onClick={this.handleClick} value='viewAll' >Todos</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick} value='boletin'>Boletin</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick} value='revista'>Revista</button>
            </div>
            <div className="ebookList-container">
                {this.filterList()}
            </div>
        </div>  
    );
}
}

export default EbookList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could store allPosts in the fetch method and implement the filtering algorithm in the filterList method

Something like that should work

```
filterList = () => {
    if(this.state.filterBy === 'boletin'){
        return getBoletin(this.state.allPosts);
    } else if (this.state.filterBy === 'revista'){
        return getRevista(this.state.allPosts);
    } else if (this.state.filterBy === 'viewAll'){
        return this.state.allPosts;
    }
}

getBoletin = (posts) => {
    return posts.map(post => {
    //tag 17 is revista
    //tag 16 is boletin
    if(post.tags.includes(16)){
        return <Ebook ebookData={post} key={post.id} />
    } return null;
  });
}

getRevista = (posts) => {
    return posts.map(post => {
    //tag 17 is revista
    //tag 16 is boletin
    if(post.tags.includes(17)){
        return <Ebook ebookData={post} key={post.id} />
    }return null;
  });
}

....
```

Comment: Yeah i get the idea behind this, and is what I would like to achieve, but then im not sure what to store inside state{allPosts} because that state is storing JSX with components and attributes, it's not storing the whole response as an object or anything. I have tried storing the whole response in state, but when i console log it it just says [object] and i can't see any of the actual values. So this method you suggest would work once I am able to store the whole json response into state, rather than an iterated array. Not sure how to store the whole response as an object

Comment: actually I've tried a few things now, I think you're completely right, let me try this out and ill get back to you in a bit

Comment: To change an array to an object you can use reduce() method - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: thanks a lot! This helped me out so much. I was able to reduce the complexity even further thanks to this

Comment: No worries. Also you could get rid of the if statement in your map operation with the following. posts.filter(post => post.tags.includes(16)).map(post => <Ebook ebookData={post} key={post.id} />). You'd avoid the null element and get something a bit easier to read.