# Javascript Array to Object best way

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following

```
 {
 bill: [ 
        { satisfy: 'true', comments: '' } 
       ],
 permission_title: [ 
        { satisfy: 'false', comments: '5' } 
       ],
 final_status: [ 
       { satisfy: 'true', comments: '' } 
       ] 
 }
```

And i need to send:

```
{
 bill: { satisfy: 'true', comments: '' },
 permission_title: { satisfy: 'false', comments: '5' },
 final_status: { satisfy: 'true', comments: '' } 
 }
```

What is the best and fast way to get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/locropulenton/uduzbn9a/2/

Comment: @sumit Does not look like a duplicate of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your object is named **obj**. I would do it this way:

```
for(var p in obj) obj[p] = obj[p][0];
```

```js
const obj={
 bill: [ 
        { satisfy: 'true', comments: '' } 
       ],
 permission_title: [ 
        { satisfy: 'false', comments: '5' } 
       ],
 final_status: [ 
       { satisfy: 'true', comments: '' } 
       ] 
 }
let obj_new=Object.assign(obj);
for(var p in obj_new) { obj_new[p] = obj_new[p][0] };
console.log(obj_new);
```

Comment: Easiest and cleanest way, I included the  fiddle

Comment: This assumes it's ok to modify the original `obj`.

Comment: we can add one additional line object.assign on the top of loop

Answer (score 2):

Extract the key/value pairs (entries) with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). Iterate the entries with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). For each entry return an object with the key, and the value without the wrapping array. Merge back to an object by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const obj = {"bill":[{"satisfy":"true","comments":""}],"permission_title":[{"satisfy":"false","comments":"5"}],"final_status":[{"satisfy":"true","comments":""}]};

const result = Object.assign(
  ...Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ({
    [k]: v[0]
  }))
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every value has only one index, an alternative is using the function `reduce` along with the function `Object.keys`.

```js
var obj = {  bill: [{    satisfy: 'true',    comments: ''  }],  permission_title: [{    satisfy: 'false',    comments: '5'  }],  final_status: [{    satisfy: 'true',    comments: ''  }]},
    result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, k) => (Object.assign(a, {[k]: obj[k][0]})), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const src = {
 bill: [ 
        { satisfy: 'true', comments: '' } 
       ],
 permission_title: [ 
        { satisfy: 'false', comments: '5' } 
       ],
 final_status: [ 
       { satisfy: 'true', comments: '' } 
       ] 
 };
 
 const dest = Object.keys(src).reduce((prev, key) => {
    prev[key] = src[key][0];
    return prev;
 }, {});
 
 console.log(dest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure efficiency wise, but you can use the find function too!

```js
const src = {
 bill: [ 
        { satisfy: 'true', comments: '' } 
       ],
 permission_title: [ 
        { satisfy: 'false', comments: '5' } 
       ],
 final_status: [ 
       { satisfy: 'true', comments: '' } 
       ] 
 };
 
 const dest = Object.keys(src).reduce((prev, key) => {
    if(Array.isArray(src[key])) {
        prev[key] = src[key].find(() => true);
    }
    
    return prev;
 }, {});
 
 console.log(dest);
```