# Convert Array groups into object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array. And i want to convert them into a group of objects.

below is my array

```
[ null,
[ 5, 6 ],
[ 7, 8 ],
[ 9, 10 ],
[ 13, 14 ] ]
```

Then i tried them to convert into object by pairs but what i had was this:

```
{ '0': null,
'1': [ 5, 6 ],
'2': [ 7, 8 ],
'3': [ 9, 10 ],
'4': [ 13, 14 ] }
```

What i'm trying to achieve is something like below:

```
    {
        "0": 5,
        "1": 6,
    },
    {
        "0": 7,
        "1": 8,
    },
    {
        "0": 9,
        "1": 10,
    },
    {
        "0": 13,
        "1": 14,
    },
```

thank you for those who will help

Comment: What you tried? please attach the relevant code  to the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object

Comment: @AkhilAravind bro yeah i saw that post and im having the above result and not the result i wanted. I believe that code is for when you have a single array but it coulde be reused and needs a bit of tweaks in order to achieve my goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a condition that skip the `null` value in the array:

```js
function changeArray(arr){
  var res = [];
  arr.forEach((item)=>{
    let obj = {};
    if(item){
      item.forEach((val, index)=>{
        obj[index] = val;
      });
     res.push(obj);
    }
  });
  return res;
}

var arr1 = [ null,
[ 5, 6 ],
[ 7, 8 ],
[ 9, 10 ],
[ 13, 14 ] ];
console.log(changeArray(arr1));

var arr2 = [ null,
[ 5, 6, 7 ],
[ 7, 8, 9 ]];
console.log(changeArray(arr2));
```

Comment: How do i turn this into a function? im kinda new to js

Comment: @Tramyer see the updated answer. If you are new then use simple loop like above instead of complex `filter` and `map` operations. So that you can learn the code style and logic.

Comment: thanks mate i've been trying to convert yours into a function but damn im having the same result. Good to see some people here it really helps the new ones.

Comment: @Tramyer glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You could filter [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values and map objects where you have assigned the array.

```js
var array = [null, [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [13, 14]],
    result = array
        .filter(Boolean)
        .map(a => Object.assign({}, a));
        
console.log(result);
```

Wrapped in a function

```js
function getObjects(array) {
    return array
        .filter(Boolean)
        .map(a => Object.assign({}, a));
}

console.log(getObjects([null, [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [13, 14]]));
```

Comment: tried your code but when i tried to create a function with it. im having the same result above.