# How to convert an array of key–value arrays to an array of individual objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, javascript-objects

I have an array of arrays that I want to turn into an array of objects in JavaScript.

Input:

```
[
  [ "foo", 1.0 ],
  [ "bar", 3.2 ],
  [ "baz", 2.1 ]
]
```

Output:

```
[
  { "foo": 1.0 },
  { "bar": 3.2 },
  { "baz": 2.1 }
]
```

Comment: One-liner: `arr.map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}))`.

Comment: [This question has already been answered in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: @FahadulIslam that is not a valid duplicate. The input format there is not a key-value tuple, but I'm sure there is some valid duplicate question somewhere.

Comment: This question has already been answered in this thread.
[Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: @FahadulIslam That’s still not the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do something like this perhaps:

```js
arr = [
    ["foo", 1.0],
    ["bar", 3.2],
    ["baz", 2.1]
]

console.log(arr.map(e => ({[e[0]]: e[1]})));
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will work on All the browsers:

Plain native code for the understanding of conversion(code is not optimized though):

```
var ArrayObject =  [
    ["foo", 1.0],
    ["bar", 3.2],
    ["baz", 2.1]
];
var OutputArray = []
for(var i=0;i<ArrayObject.length;i++){
    var arrayObject = {}
    var ObjectProperty = ArrayObject[i][0];
    var ObjectValue = ArrayObject[i][1];
    arrayObject[ObjectProperty] = ObjectValue;
    OutputArray.push(arrayObject);
}
```