# Spread syntax in object key set not working

Tags: javascript, object, key, spread-syntax

I have an array of strings, and I want to turn it into an object where each key is a word. I'm doing this:

```
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let obj = {};
obj[...arr] = true;
```

However, it seems like this doesn't work :(

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well there are no provisions in the syntax to do what you're trying to do. Also "spread" is not an operator; it's a syntax convention. It's not part of the expression syntax, which is where operators live.

Comment: Guess I just have to do it in a loop then?

Comment: I don't know any other way to do that. Maybe some smarty person does however.

Comment: I can probably use reduce

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in a slightly more succinct way:

```js
const fill = v => (o, k) => ({ ...o, [k]: v })
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
let obj = arr.reduce(fill(true), {})

console.log(obj)
```

If you really don't like copying the accumulator `o` each iteration, you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Assign) instead:

```js
const fill = v => (o, k) => Object.assign(o, { [k]: v })
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
let obj = arr.reduce(fill(true), {})

console.log(obj)
```

Or even just

```js
const fill = v => k => ({ [k]: v })
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
let obj = Object.assign(...arr.map(fill(true)))

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: @OlivierBoissé you should try it yourself and find out what you get ;)

Comment: @OlivierBoissé ah no worries. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373577/1541563 I'm currently in the middle of fixing up a misused tag as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

Using `forEach` is shorter.

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var obj = {}

arr.forEach(e=>obj[e]=true)

console.log(obj)
```

But you could use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) that is probably faster.

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var obj = arr.reduce((acc,c,i)=>{
    acc[c] = true; return acc;
},{})

console.log(obj)
```

To do the opposite, you could use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
var obj = {
    "a": true,
    "b": true,
    "c": true
  }
var arr = [...Object.keys(obj)];

console.log(arr)
```

Spread syntax needs an iterable such as an array, but could be an object, see this about [iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). In the case above, we are using `Object.keys(obj)` that returns an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` function to fill the `obj` with true values

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const obj = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
   acc[val] = true;
   return acc;
 }, {});
    
console.log(obj);
```