# How to convert array to object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
const x = [
    {event: "oninput", action: ""},
    {event: "onfocus", action: ""}
]
```

Following is the desired output:

```
// event: action
{
    oninput: "",
    onfocus: ""
}
```

I tried the following which didn't really work:

```js
const x = [
    {event: "oninput", action: ""},
    {event: "onfocus", action: ""}
]

console.log({...x.map(y => {return {[y.event]: y.action}})})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: `.map` returns an array, spreading it into an object will result in numeric-indexed properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and map the objects. This collects all objects and assign it to a single object.

```js
const x = [
    { event: "oninput", action: "" },
    { event: "onfocus", action: "" }
];

console.log(Object.assign(...x.map(({ event, action }) => ({ [event]: action }))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *reduce* to build a new object. It also gives compatibility back to ECMAScript 2011:

```js
var x = [
    {event: "oninput", action: ""},
    {event: "onfocus", action: ""}
];

var o = x.reduce((acc, obj) => {acc[obj.event] = obj.action; return acc}, {});

console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Different approach:

```
const x = [
    {event: "oninput", action: ""},
    {event: "onfocus", action: ""}
]
let newObj = {}
x.forEach(obj => {
    newObj[obj.event] = obj.action
})


console.log(newObj)
// returns { oninput: '', onfocus: '' }
```