# Convert an array of ojects to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular, object

What I wanted to achieved is convert an array of object into an object.

## mycode

```
 var arr = data.questions
        var obj = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            obj[arr[i].key] = arr[i].value;
        }
        console.log(obj)
```

## result

```
data 
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: 48, questionaire: 94, question: "Helloworld", input_answer: null, order: 0, …}
1: {id: 49, questionaire: 94, question: "sadasdas", input_answer: null, order: 1, …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

## want to achieve

```
questions {id: 11, questionaire: 16, question: "what?", input_answer: null, order: 0, …}
```

Comment: give the real code instead of copying from console

Comment: Expecting each of the object to have same set of keys. In that case you cannot convert it to `object` since an object cannot have duplicate key

Comment: What will be unique in your case? As object should have unique key

Comment: What is `data.questions`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = [
    {id: 48, questionaire: 94, question: "Helloworld", input_answer: null, order: 0},
    {id: 49, questionaire: 94, question: "sadasdas", input_answer: null, order: 1}
];

const output = input.reduce((a, obj)=>{
    a[obj.id] = obj;
    return a;
}, {});

console.log(output);
// Or you can access the specific objects using there keys
console.log(output[48]);
console.log(output[49]);
```

If there is only one object in the array, then you can simply access the object using `index`.

```js
var array = [{id: 44, questionaire: 90, question: "asd", input_answer: null, order: 0}];

console.log(array[0]);
```

Comment: @how about there are multiple objects in an array?

Comment: @JanMichaelDough - provide input and output you want.

Comment: data 
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: 48, questionaire: 94, question: "Helloworld", input_answer: null, order: 0, …}
1: {id: 49, questionaire: 94, question: "sadasdas", input_answer: null, order: 1, …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Where is the output?

Comment: here is that catch i want to seperate it as two objects

Comment: @JanMichaelDough - I am not really sure how you want actual result, I have updated my code, where I had created a single object with id as key and assigned the whole object to it and later you can access the specific objects using there id's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign()`

```js
var a = [{
  a: 1
}, {
  b: 2
}, {
  c: 3
}]
var obj = {};
a.forEach(e => {
  Object.assign(obj, e)
})
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: It is working here. Don't know what is not working for you. If you care to elaborate?