# Issue with Immutable Update Pattern in Redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux, reducers

I am trying to update a nested array filed in **redux reducer**, here is my array i want to update ( just add **updating:true** filed ) my array looks like

I want to add a **updating:true** filed on room object after number filed

```
items: Array(1)
    0:
    name: (2) [{…}, {…}]
    rooms: Array(2)
        0: {_id: "5d494e5b11b962065632c760", number: "100" …}
        1: {_id: "5d494e6211b962065632c761", number: "102" …}
```

look like

```
items :
     [{
        name: [{}],
        rooms : [{}]
     }]
```

Here is my redux reducer code, i am trying to update

```
case Constants.Status_ADD_REQUEST:
var ID = ID; // action id

return {...state,
  items:[{...state.items, 
        rooms:[{...state.items.rooms, 
            rooms:{...state.items.rooms.map(x=> x._id === ID ? {...x,updating: true} :  x )}}]
 }]
};
```

anyway its not working  :) please guide me to correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a second look at the [spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in JavaScript, especially spread for array literals. For example in your reducer, you create a new state with an `items` array containing only one *fix* object (it would still be only one object, even if you would add more items in your example). This item object contains your previous [converted and spread items array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36388401/5669456) and `rooms` property - not really your state shape.

How you could create the state instead:

[Full example repo (with TypeScript)](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-57442831-6wgne)

```
const initialState = {...}

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Constants.Status_ADD_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: state.items.map(item =>
          item.rooms.some(i => i.id === action.id)
            ? {
                ...item,
                rooms: item.rooms.map(room =>
                  room.id === action.id ? { ...room, updating: true } : room
                )
              }
            : item
        )
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

in the style of ["Updating an Item in an Array" Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array).

If you have to ensure [immutable patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) this way and manually, things will get ugly fast. Reason: The key to updating nested data is that every level of nesting must be copied and updated appropriately (structural sharing).

To circumvent those problems, your goal should be to [keep your state flattened](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) and to [compose reducers](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/refactoring-reducer-example). If cloning your state still becomes too complex, you could make use of [Immutable Update Utility Libraries](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#immutable-update-utility-libraries). I personally can recommend [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer), as you can change state in a mutable way, while the library takes care of deep clones/structural sharing via JavaScript proxies transparently.

PS: It could also make sense to think of another name for "update room", if it is some of your [domain/app data](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/basic-reducer-structure#basic-state-shape).