# Make two arrays into json data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Lets Say I have

```
A = [cat,dog,horse]
B = [angry,happy,sad]

call = {}
```

How can I make json object which looks like this

```
console.log(call.animal[2]) // horse

console.log(call.mood[2]) // sad
```

Comment: `call = { animal : A, mood : B}` ? or `call = {}; call.animal = A; call.mood = B` ?

Comment: Are you asking how to turn this into JSON or how to merge two arrays into an object? Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `a` as the `animal` property of `call`, and `b` as the `mood` property of `call`:

```
call = { animal: A, mood: B };
```

If the arrays are meant to be of strings, then make sure to put `'` around each string, like

```
A = ['cat', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As easy as this. This is a new feature of es6, animals and emotions variables become a key-value (variable name and its value) in an object.

```js
const animals = ['cat','dog','horse'];
const emotions = ['angry','happy','sad'];

const call = {animals, emotions};

console.log(call.animals[2], call.emotions[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your array is string.

```js
const a = ['cat','dog','horse'];
const b = ['angry','happy','sad'];

call = {
  animal : a,
  fruit : b
}

console.log(call.animal[1]);
```