# Transform nested array of objects to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to convert a nested array to an object, I made several attempts but without success.

**these are the data i have**

```
[
  ['key1', { childKey1: "text" }, { childKey2: "text" }],
  ['key2', { childKey1: "text" }, { childKey2: "text" }]
]
```

**this is the data i need**

```
{
  key1: {
    childKey1: "text",
    childKey2: "text"
  },
  key2: {
    childKey1: "text",
    childKey2: "text"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: you can do this with reduce. what did you try?

Comment: reduce i haven't tried yet

Comment: This is not JSON. [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131/1218980)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map the data to entries - [[key, value], [key, value]]. Use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) to get the key (the 1st item in a sub-array), and [rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_the_rest_of_an_array_to_a_variable) to get an array of objects. Merge the array of objects by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) the array of objects into [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to get the value. Use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert the entries to an object.

```js
const data = [['key1', {childKey1: "text"}, {childKey2: "text"}], ['key2', {childKey1: "text"}, {childKey2: "text"}]]

const result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(
  ([k, ...v]) => [k, Object.assign({}, ...v)]
))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

[.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method is another way to approach this.

```js
const arr = [['key1', {childKey1: "text"}, {childKey2: "text"}], ['key2', {childKey1: "text"}, {childKey2: "text"}]];

const newArr = arr.reduce((accumulator, currVal) => {
  const [key, ...values] = currVal; // destruct array and separate key from all other values
  
  accumulator[key] = Object.assign({}, ...values); // assign values to your final object, using the key extracted above
  
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try reduce to achieve such task. You could do something like this:

```js
    const data = [
      ["key1", { childKey1: "text" }, { childKey2: "text" }],
      ["key2", { childKey1: "text" }, { childKey2: "text" }]
    ];
    
    function dataToJSON(data) {
      return data.reduce((acc, current) => {
        const [key, ...values] = current;
        acc[key] = Object.assign({}, ...values);
        return acc;
      }, {});
    }

    console.log(dataToJSON(data));
```

Works perfect for any number of children. You have to be careful with repeated keys not to overwrite a previous one.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was already answered, but here's my attempt at it:

```js
let jsonArray = [['key1', {childKey1: "text"}, {childKey2: "text"}], ['key2', {childKey1: "text"}, {childKey2: "text"}]];
let newJson  = {};

for(var i=0; i<jsonArray.length; i++){
 newJson[jsonArray[i][0]] = Object.assign({}, ...jsonArray[i].slice(1));
}

console.log(newJson);
```