# JavaScript how to extract array properties into another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

I need to map an array coming from a server to change its fields into fields that are understandable by another server, so I can upload it into the second server.

My first challenge is to get the field names of the first array coming from the first server, display them to the user, to edit them and then using `array.map()` I will create a new array with the user defined field names.

My first step is to get the array main field names. Lets say I have the following:

```
array = [{'name': 'John', 'lastname' :'Doe'},{'name': 'Roe', 'lastname' :'Doe'}]
```

The result would be like:

```
arrayFields = [{name, lastname}]
```

I tried to use `getOwnPropertyNames()`:

```
getProp(){
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.array))
}
```

The result was like:

> ["0", "1", "length"]
>
> 0: "0"
>
> 1: "1"
>
> 2: "length"

I then tried with `Object.assign()` as mentioned in this stack [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object):

```
 getObject(){
    let newObject = (Object.assign(this.array))
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(newObject))
 }
```

But it was the same as previous result.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zcqibb) I am working with.

The wanted result is like: `["name", "lastname"]`

Comment: `arrayFields = [{name, lastname}]` but what is the value of those properties? Because you have an *object* and objects have key-value pairs. If you only want the keys as an array `["name", "lastname"]` then simply get those using `Object.keys(array[0])` assuming all values have the same structure.

Comment: please add the wanted result to the question.

Comment: @NinaScholz added

Comment: has your objects have always the same properties?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) combination also. By using them you have **more flexible way** to extract all the properties from each elements of the original array. For example if you have different properties in some elements.

Try the following:

```js
const array = [{'name': 'John', 'lastname' :'Doe'},{'name': 'Roe', 'lastname' :'Doe'}];

const result = new Set(array.flatMap(e => Object.keys(e), []));

console.log(Array.from(result));
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: `.reduce` is an overkill when you can just use `.map`

Comment: @VLAZ That's right, I just changed to `.flatMap()` that works better for this case.

Answer (score 1):

If they're all in the same format, you can take the first element and extract its keys:

```js
const a = [{'name': 'John', 'lastname' :'Doe'},{'name': 'Roe', 'lastname' :'Doe'}];
const dummyEntry = a[0];
console.log(Object.keys(dummyEntry));
```

For your objects it would give `[ "name", "lastname" ]`

Comment: What happens when we have different structure for each elements? I mean the solution is good until we have extra properties in the second element in the original array.

Comment: Hence "If they're all in the same format". If they're not, better off to use combination of set and map as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Your getProp() function is almost correct, except you need to call getOwnPropertyNames on an element within the array:

```js
getProp(){
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.array[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variant would be:

```
let keySet = new Set();
this.array.forEach(e => Object.keys(e).forEach(i => keySet.add(i)));
console.log("keySet : ", Array.from(keySet));
```