# Hi all, How to convert Javascript Array to Object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this array

```
[ 0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c']
```

I want convert this array to an object

```
{ 'a': true, 'b': true, 'c': true }
```

What is the best way ?

Comment: do you have tried anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: yes, but i can't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

```js
array.reduce((acc, value) => {
  acc[value] = true;
  return acc;
})
```

Have a look at [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Answer (score 1):

You could map entries from the array and get an object.

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    result = Object.fromEntries(array.map(k => [k, true]));

console.log(result);
```