# How do i add a random JSON-Part to a JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, json

let´s assume i have a json message:

json_msg =

```
[{ LOG: 'TPT',
  TYPE: 'UPDATE',
  UIN: 'VEHICLE',
  SEQ_NO: 20129,
  VALUE: 1,
  TIMESTAMP: 518342.438263017,
  EXPERIMENT: 0,
  IDENT: '.Model.Index_obj.MuLifeCycle_obj.Mu.vh_Transporter:2',
  STAGE: 'START',
  MODE: '' },
{ LOG: 'TPT',
  TYPE: 'UPDATE',
  UIN: 'VEHICLE',
  SEQ_NO: 20129,
  VALUE: 1,
  TIMESTAMP: 518342.438263017,
  EXPERIMENT: 0,
  IDENT: '.Model.Index_obj.MuLifeCycle_obj.Mu.vh_Transporter:2',
  STAGE: 'START',
  MODE: '' }.
{ LOG: 'TPT',
  TYPE: 'UPDATE',
  UIN: 'VEHICLE',
  SEQ_NO: 20129,
  VALUE: 1,
  TIMESTAMP: 518342.438263017,
  EXPERIMENT: 0,
  IDENT: '.Model.Index_obj.MuLifeCycle_obj.Mu.vh_Transporter:2',
  STAGE: 'START',
  MODE: '' }]
```

and  i want to append it to an empty json object

```
var testObject = {}
```

and now i want to use a loop in order to append these json-messages in *testObject*

```
for (let i =0; i< json_msg.length; i++) {
     // TODO 
     testObject.push(json_msg[i])} // does not work
```

Somebody has an idea?

Note that this is a test-case. My real-life example filters incoming json messages and i want a class method that appends these filtered messages into a new JSON Object message (same like '.push' for arrays).

Comment: what do you expect the resultant object to look like?

Comment: testObject is an object, .push() works on an array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: @SvenWritesCode the result should be an JSON Object itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do this in 3 ways 
with `Object.assign` or `{...}` or with loops

```js
let data= [{ "LOG": 'TPT',
  "TYPE": 'UPDATE',
  "UIN": 'VEHICLE',
  "SEQ_NO": 20129,
  "VALUE": 1,
  "TIMESTAMP": 518342.438263017,
  "EXPERIMENT": 0,
  "IDENT": '.Model.Index_obj.MuLifeCycle_obj.Mu.vh_Transporter:2',
  "STAGE": 'START',
  "MODE": '' },{ "LOG": 'TPT',
  "TYPE": 'UPDATE',
  "UIN": 'VEHICLE',
  "SEQ_NO": 20129,
  "VALUE": 1,
  "TIMESTAMP": 518342.438263017,
  "EXPERIMENT": 0,
  "IDENT": '.Model.Index_obj.MuLifeCycle_obj.Mu.vh_Transporter:2',
  "STAGE": 'START',
  "MODE": '' },{ "LOG": 'TPT',
  "TYPE": 'UPDATE',
  "UIN": 'VEHICLE',
  "SEQ_NO": 20129,
  "VALUE": 1,
  "TIMESTAMP": 518342.438263017,
  "EXPERIMENT": 0,
  "IDENT": '.Model.Index_obj.MuLifeCycle_obj.Mu.vh_Transporter:2',
  "STAGE": 'START',
  "MODE": '' }
]
  
  let newObject={...data}
  
  console.log("newObject:",newObject)
  ////or
  let newObject2=Object.assign({},data)
  console.log("newObject2:",newObject2)
  ////or loop
  let newObject3={}
  data.forEach((x,i)=>
  newObject3[i]=x
  )
    console.log("newObject3:",newObject3)
```