# Set array values to different keys of object

Tags: javascript

hi so i followed this question : [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object): but apparently there are great answers but not what i require.
I have an array like this : `["123","jhon","doe","hawaii"]`
What i want to be able to do is make an object that looks like this :
`{id:"123",fname:"jhon",lname:"doe",location:"hawaii"}`

Basically i want to assign the values of the array to fix keys for each value. I tried looping over them but that would replace the current object key if i do something like.

```
let obj = {}
arr.map(val=>{
 obj.id = val
})
```

This will obviously not work. Any ideas or can you point me in the right direction would also help thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using the for-loop over the array to add to a new object the properties. The name of the properties are stored in a const-array, so you can add more later if necessary. The number of elments had to be same in both arrays.

```js
let arr = ["123","jhon","doe","hawaii"];
const KEYS = ['id', 'fname', 'lname', 'location']; 
let obj = {};

for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    obj[KEYS[i]] = arr[i];
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: i'll test now but since you took out the time i'll upvote anyways thanks.:)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a second array of keys (in your example you're trying to define every value to the key `id`) which is the same size as the data-array, and then between the two of them you can generate an object:

```js
var values = ['123', 'jhon', 'doe', 'hawaii'];
var keys = ['id', 'fname', 'lname', 'location'];
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
   obj[keys[i]] = values[i];
}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: i'll test now but since you took out the time i'll upvote anyways thanks.:)

Comment: You must not use a big "L"

Answer (score 1):

Using Array#reduce() and computed properties

```js
const values = ["123", "jhon", "doe", "hawaii"],
      keys = ["id", "fname", "lname", "location"];

const res = keys.reduce((a, c, i) => ({...a, [c] : values[i]}), {})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: i'll test now but since you took out the time i'll upvote anyways thanks.:)

Answer (score 1):

**Here's an interesting way to solve it.**

```js
keys = ["id","fname","lname","location"];
values = ["123","jhon","doe","hawaii"];
obj = {};
keys.forEach((key, i) => (obj = {...obj, [key]: values[i]}));

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your yehr

```
keys = ["id","fname","lname","location"];
values = ["123","jhon","doe","hawaii"];
var result = {};
keys.forEach((key, i) => result[key] = values[i]);
console.log(result)
```