# JavaScript: convert an array of string to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings: `const names = ['name1', 'name2', name3']`

And I need the following array of objects:

`const newArray = [{ name: 'name1' }, { name: 'name2' }, { name: 'name3' }]`

How can I create `newArray` from `names`, or even possibly convert `names` itself without creating brand new array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: `const names = ['name1', 'name2', name3'].map(n => ({name: n}))`

Comment: Example: `const newArray = [...names.map(e => ({name: e}))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily achieved with the `map` function.

```
const newArray = names.map((name) => {
    return {
      name
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can do that for you:

```js
const names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];

const newArray = names.map(x=>{return{name:x};});
console.log(newArray);
```