# How can we modify javascript array to array object?

Tags: javascript

I have this array `arr = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:5},{id:5}]`
I want to modify array  like index 0 - 1 is first, 2 -3 is second, 4 - 5 is third and so on

Result array:
`[first:[{id:1},{id:2}],second:[{id:3},{id:5}],third:[{id:5}]]`

How can I modify array in such type?

Comment: Have a look at [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp) forEach documentation

Comment: Could you please give more detail for the output generate rules?

Comment: You can use forEach, map, a while loop, or a for loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you are expecting is not a valid array.

```
[first: [{},{}]]
```

It should be either an array like this

```
[[{},{}],[{},{}]]
```

or an object

```
{"first":[{},{}],"second":[{},{}]}
```

The code below converts your input to an array, it can be easily modified to an object if that's what you are looking for with some small modifications.

```
const arr = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 5 }];
let result = arr.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
  if (index % 2 == 0) {
    acc.push([current]);
  } else {
    acc[Math.floor(index / 2)].push(current);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.map`. This example returns the id value of each multiplied by the number it exists in the array.

```js
let arr = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:5},{id:5}];
arr.map(function(item,index) {
    return item.id * index;
})
```

Try it out!