# Converting array into object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert Array into object

For example:

I want to convert, below array into

```js
var a = ['a','b','c','d']
```

Below object

```js
var obj = {
  'a': {
    'b': {
      'c': {
        'd': 'any value'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any one have any idea ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: No this is not my question

Comment: The question should be reopened, Object.assign, spread, or similar in the duplicate question won't nest the properties. `['a','b','c','d'].reverse().reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc) return { [curr]: { ...acc } };
  return { [curr]: 'any value' };
}, null);`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky the link posted by Shreyas isn't the one used to close this question. See the link at the very top. The answer there does indeed nest the properties

Comment: @Alexander Staroselsky your answer solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: @Phil You're absolutely right, missed that link, that solution would definitely solve it and is cleaner.