# Convert array values to objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code

```
const jsonArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I want to convert it so I can get

```
{
 "id" : 1
},
{
 "id" : 2
},
{
 "id" : 3
},
{
 "id" : 4
},
{
 "id" : 5
}
```

So I need to add "id" key for all the objects outputs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: @poPaTheGuru not the same

Comment: I want the keys to be "id" not numbers

Comment: `jsonArray.map(id => ({ id }))`

Comment: `jsonArray.map(elem => ({ id: elem }));`

Comment: @Jacquesジャック Doesn't work, you're not returning anything from the block

Comment: Please be aware that the input and output data is not JSON.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković You're right, since it's returning an object I cannot use the shorthand return. My mistake.

 `const myObj = jsonArray.map((val) => { return {id: val}});`

Comment: @Jacquesジャック You can, you just have to wrap the object in parens like this: `(val) => ({ id: val })`

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković You're correct, but I hate that syntax as it's easy to think they're just double wrapped in curlys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the map function

```
jsonObjectArray = jsonArray.map((ele) => {return {"id": ele}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map.

```
jsonArray.map(id=>({id}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for that:

```js
const jsonArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
        
const arrayofObjects = jsonArray.map(e => ({id: e}))

console.log(arrayofObjects);
```